# Most pythonic way of assigning keyword arguments using a variable as keyword?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

What is **the most pythonic way** to get around the following problem? From the interactive shell:

```
>>> def f(a=False):
...     if a:
...         return 'a was True'
...     return 'a was False'
... 
>>> f(a=True)
'a was True'
>>> kw = 'a'
>>> val = True
>>> f(kw=val)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kw'
```

For the moment I'm getting around it with the following:

```
>>> exec 'result = f(%s=val)' % kw
>>> result
'a was True'
```

but it seems quite clumsy...

(Either python 2.7+ or 3.2+ solutions are ok)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use [keyword argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments):

```
>>> kw = {'a': True}

>>> f(**kw)
<<< 'a was True'
```

Answer (score 7):

In many circumstances you can just use

```
f(kw)
```

as keyword arguments don't have to be specified as keywords, if you specify all arguments before them.

Python 3 has a syntax for [keyword only arguments](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/), but that's not what they are by default.

Or, building on @zeekay's answer,

```
kw = 'a'
f(**{kw: True})
```

if you don't want to store kw as a dict, for example if you're also using it as a key in a dictionary lookup elsewhere.