# Constructing pandas DataFrame from values in variables gives "ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, valueerror, scalar

I have two variables as follows.

```py
a = 2
b = 3
```

I want to construct a DataFrame from this:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':a, 'B':b})
```

This generates an error:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

I tried this also:

```py
df2 = (pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b})).reset_index()
```

This gives the same error message. How do I do what I want?

Comment: Am I missing something? isn't it trivial that no `.foo()` would solve the error since the exception is produced when evaluating the DataFrame constructor?

Answer (score 1197, accepted):

The error message says that if you're passing scalar values, you have to pass an index.  So you can either not use scalar values for the columns -- e.g. use a list:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [a], 'B': [b]})
>>> df
   A  B
0  2  3
```

or use scalar values and pass an index:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': a, 'B': b}, index=[0])
>>> df
   A  B
0  2  3
```

Comment: Perhaps it is because the order of items in a list in Python are persistent whereas the ordering of items in a dictionary are not. You can instantiate a DataFrame with an empty dictionary. In principle I suppose a single-row DataFrame as shown here would also be ok to build from a dictionary because the order does not matter (but this hasn't been implemented). However with multiple rows, Pandas would not be able to make a DataFrame because it would not know which items belonged to the same row.

Comment: @VitalyIsaev - In that case, the dataframe row (represented by the given dictionary) has no index (not even an implicit one). 
A simple solution is to wrap the dictionary within a list, which does have "natural indexing".

One can claim that if only one dictionary is given (without a wrapping list), then assume `index=0`, but that can lead to accidental misuse (thinking that a single dictionary can somehow create a multi-row dataframe)

Comment: several solutions in this link https://eulertech.wordpress.com/2017/11/28/pandas-valueerror-if-using-all-scalar-values-you-must-pass-an-index/

Comment: The reason for this is because DataFrames are meant to hold two-dimensional data (i.e. rows of OP's two variables). If you want to simply hold index -> value pairs (like a Dictionary), then you should use a Series, as [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36670644/235463) suggests.

Comment: This is a single sample/row Dataframe, so index = [0] makes logical sense; but you could also manipulate it to be index=[100], which works. Q: Isn't Index supposed to logically ordered incrementally, why does python allow Index manipulation?

Comment: Is there anything bad that happens if only one element is in a list? So `{'a': [1], 'b': 2}`? I have found I can get away with placing just one of the dict values in a list.

Comment: For big dictionaries use: >>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict_name, index=range(n))

Answer (score 250):

You may try wrapping your dictionary into a list:

```py
my_dict = {'A':1,'B':2}
pd.DataFrame([my_dict])
```

```
   A  B
0  1  2
```

Comment: This is great. Adding a `.transpose()` is useful for most practical cases to convert wide to long, i.e. `pd.DataFrame([my_dict]).transpose()`

Answer (score 110):

You can also use `pd.DataFrame.from_records` which is more convenient when you already have the dictionary in hand:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([{ 'A':a,'B':b }])
```

You can also set index, if you want, by:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([{ 'A':a,'B':b }], index='A')
```

Comment: @DaveKielpinski Please, check if you passed a *list* to the "from_records" method; otherwise it won't work, and you'll get the same error message as when you call DataFrame on the dictionary.

Comment: Same issue as @DaveKielpinski until I realised I was using `from_records` on individual documents, not on an array of such. Just posting this in case it reminds you to double check whether you're doing it right.

Comment: @mingchau:  That's standard behavior, so not relevant to the question at hand.

Answer (score 86):

You need to create a pandas series first. The second step is to convert the pandas series to pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
pd.Series(data).to_frame()
```

You can even provide a column name.

```
pd.Series(data).to_frame('ColumnName')
```

Comment: This worked for me. My dictionary had integer keys and ndarray values.

Comment: `pd.Series(data).to_frame('ColumnName')`
is shorter, although this equivalent is perhaps more direct:
`pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index', columns=['ColumnName'])`

Comment: This worked for me, too, in the same case as @StatsSorceress.

Comment: This doesn't create the same structure as asked. with this approach I got a dataframe with 1 column and two rows (A and B), but the results should be a datafarme with 1 row and two columns (A and B)

Comment: @shlomiLan This is the structure I wanted, and what I figured the OP was looking for based on the question. Though the fact that they accepted the answer which has a single row indicates otherwise....

Answer (score 18):

Maybe Series would provide all the functions you need:

```
pd.Series({'A':a,'B':b})
```

DataFrame can be thought of as a collection of Series hence you can :

- Concatenate multiple Series into one data frame (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062135/combining-two-series-into-a-dataframe-in-pandas) )
- Add a Series variable into existing data frame ( [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas) )

Comment: This is the golden answer - then reassign the series back to a column (e.g. when using `df.apply()`)

Answer (score 14):

Pandas magic at work. All logic is out.

The error message `"ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index"` Says you must pass an index.

This does not necessarily mean passing an index makes pandas do **what you want it to do**

When you pass an index, pandas will treat your dictionary keys as column names and the values as what the column should contain for each of the values in the index.

```
a = 2
b = 3
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':a,'B':b}, index=[1])

    A   B
1   2   3
```

Passing a larger index:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':a,'B':b}, index=[1, 2, 3, 4])

    A   B
1   2   3
2   2   3
3   2   3
4   2   3
```

An index is usually automatically generated by a dataframe when none is given. However, pandas does not know how many rows of `2` and `3` you want. You can however be more explicit about it

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[a]*4,'B':[b]*4})
df2

    A   B
0   2   3
1   2   3
2   2   3
3   2   3
```

The default index is 0 based though.

I would recommend always passing a dictionary of lists to the dataframe constructor when creating dataframes. It's easier to read for other developers. Pandas has a lot of caveats, don't make other developers have to experts in all of them in order to read your code.

Comment: This explanation was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 14):

I usually use the following to to quickly create a small table from dicts.

Let's say you have a dict where the keys are filenames and the values their corresponding filesizes, you could use the following code to put it into a DataFrame (notice the .items() call on the dict):

```
files = {'A.txt':12, 'B.txt':34, 'C.txt':56, 'D.txt':78}
filesFrame = pd.DataFrame(files.items(), columns=['filename','size'])
print(filesFrame)

  filename  size
0    A.txt    12
1    B.txt    34
2    C.txt    56
3    D.txt    78
```

Comment: This is helpful but note it doesn't work on pandas 0.23.4

Comment: For me this was perfect! Having simply two rows of data in a dictionary and turning that in to a dataframe shouldn't be that hard.

Answer (score 12):

You could try:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a':a,'b':b}, orient = 'index')
```

From the documentation on the 'orient' argument: If the keys of the passed dict should be the columns of the resulting DataFrame, pass ‘columns’ (default). Otherwise if the keys should be rows, pass ‘index’.

Comment: This does not solve the question asked, it produces a different result than desired.

Comment: @KenWilliams I'm confused. It looks like this provides either the result that I thought the OP wanted, or the result that it seems you think OP wanted (and the one that MLguy though OP wanted). So it is the most flexible of all the answers with this many votes.

Comment: @nealmcb That's indeed claimed by the answerer, but when using `orient='columns'`, it just gives the same `If using all scalar values, you must pass an index` error as in the original question.  I should have clarified that point in my comment.

Answer (score 10):

You need to provide iterables as the values for the Pandas DataFrame columns:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[a],'B':[b]})
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem with numpy arrays and the solution is to flatten them:

```
data = {
    'b': array1.flatten(),
    'a': array2.flatten(),
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: There are no arrays (`array1`, `array2`) in the original question, the values are scalars.  Is this answering some different question?

Answer (score 10):

To figure out the "ValueError" understand DataFrame and "scalar values" is needed.
To create a Dataframe from **dict**, **at least one Array** is needed.

IMO, **array itself is indexed**.
Therefore, if there is an array-like value there is no need to specify index.
e.g. The index of each element in ['a', 's', 'd', 'f'] are 0,1,2,3 separately.

```
df_array_like = pd.DataFrame({
    'col' : 10086,
    'col_2' : True,
    'col_3' : "'at least one array'",
    'col_4' : ['one array is arbitrary length', 'multi arrays should be the same length']}) 
print("df_array_like: \n", df_array_like)
```

Output:

```
df_array_like: 
      col  col_2                 col_3                                   col_4
0  10086   True  'at least one array'           one array is arbitrary length
1  10086   True  'at least one array'  multi arrays should be the same length
```

As shows in the output, the index of the DataFrame is 0 and 1.
Coincidently same with the index of the array ['one array is arbitrary length', 'multi arrays should be the same length']

If comment out the 'col_4', it will raise

> ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")

Cause **scalar value** (integer, bool, and string) **does not have index**
Note that **Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind**
Since index used to locate all the rows of DataFrame
index should be an array. e.g.

```
df_scalar_value = pd.DataFrame({
'col' : 10086,
'col_2' : True,
'col_3' : "'at least one array'"
}, index = ['fst_row','snd_row','third_row']) 
print("df_scalar_value: \n", df_scalar_value)
```

Output:

```
df_scalar_value: 
              col  col_2                 col_3
fst_row    10086   True  'at least one array'
snd_row    10086   True  'at least one array'
third_row  10086   True  'at least one array'
```

I'm a beginner, I'm learning python and English.

Answer (score 9):

```py
import pandas as pd
 a=2
 b=3
dict = {'A': a, 'B': b}

pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(dict)).T  
# *T :transforms the dataframe*

   Result:
    A   B
0   2   3
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer adds `.T` to what other answers have suggested. Can you add an explanation of how this makes a difference?

Comment: There are twenty-one existing answers to this question, including an accepted answer with 836 upvotes (!!!). Are you sure your answer hasn't already been provided? If not, why might someone prefer your approach over the existing approaches proposed? Are you taking advantage of new capabilities? Are there scenarios where your approach is better suited? Explanations are _always_ useful, but are _especially_ important here.

Comment: Even I don't understand why, your solution worked for me. The other answers gave keyerror

Answer (score 7):

If **the data is a dictionary**, one way to construct a dataframe is to call `pd.json_normalize()` which constructs a flat dataframe (the index is created under the covers). Its main use case is to flatten a nested dictionary but works on a flat dictionary as well.

```py
df = pd.json_normalize({'A': 2, 'B': 3})


   A  B
0  2  3
```

In general, it's possible to construct a dataframe by first initializing an empty dataframe and then filling it by the dictionary.

- For a wide dataframe:

  ```py
  d = {'A': 2, 'B': 3}
  df = pd.DataFrame(columns=d.keys())
  df.loc[0] = d


     A  B
  0  2  3
  ```
- For a long dataframe:

  ```py
  df = pd.DataFrame()
  df['col'] = {'A': 2, 'B': 3}


     col
  A    2
  B    3
  ```

---

If **the data is some scalar values** (as in the OP), then wrap it in a list/tuple and pass to the dataframe constructor (and optionally pass column/index labels). A nested list constructs a wide dataframe and a flat list constructs a long dataframe.

```py
a = 2
b = 3

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[a, b]], columns=['A', 'B'])


   A  B
0  2  3



df2 = pd.DataFrame([a, b], columns=['A'])


   A
0  2
1  3
```

Answer (score 6):

The input does not have to be a list of records - it can be a single dictionary as well:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records({'a':1,'b':2}, index=[0])
   a  b
0  1  2
```

Which seems to be equivalent to:

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':1,'b':2}, index=[0])
   a  b
0  1  2
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a':a,'b':b}, orient = 'index')
```

Comment: This is the exact same answer posted by @MathewConnell, except without formatting...

Answer (score 5):

I tried transpose() and it worked.
Downside: You create a new object.

```
testdict1 = {'key1':'val1','key2':'val2','key3':'val3','key4':'val4'}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=testdict1,orient='index')
print(df)
print(f'ID for DataFrame before Transpose: {id(df)}\n')

df = df.transpose()
print(df)
print(f'ID for DataFrame after Transpose: {id(df)}')
```

Output

````
         0
key1  val1
key2  val2
key3  val3
key4  val4
ID for DataFrame before Transpose: 1932797100424

   key1  key2  key3  key4
0  val1  val2  val3  val4
ID for DataFrame after Transpose: 1932797125448

​```
````

Answer (score 3):

This is because a DataFrame has two intuitive dimensions - the columns *and* the rows.

You are only specifying the columns using the dictionary keys.

If you only want to specify one dimensional data, use a Series!

Answer (score 3):

If you intend to convert a dictionary of scalars, you have to include an index:

```
import pandas as pd

alphabets = {'A': 'a', 'B': 'b'}
index = [0]
alphabets_df = pd.DataFrame(alphabets, index=index)
print(alphabets_df)
```

Although index is not required for a dictionary of lists, the same idea can be expanded to a dictionary of lists:

```
planets = {'planet': ['earth', 'mars', 'jupiter'], 'length_of_day': ['1', '1.03', '0.414']}
index = [0, 1, 2]
planets_df = pd.DataFrame(planets, index=index)
print(planets_df)
```

Of course, for the dictionary of lists, you can build the dataframe without an index:

```
planets_df = pd.DataFrame(planets)
print(planets_df)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your 'a' and 'b' values to a list, as follows:

```
a = [2]
b = [3]
```

then execute the same code as follows:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':a,'B':b})
df2
```

and you'll get:

```
    A   B
0   2   3
```

Answer (score 2):

simplest options ls :

```
dict  = {'A':a,'B':b}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict, index = np.arange(1) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to convert the scalars into list on the fly using Dictionary Comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={k: [v] for k, v in mydict.items()})
```

The expression {...} creates a new dict whose values is a list of 1 element. such as :

```
In [20]: mydict
Out[20]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

In [21]: mydict2 = { k: [v] for k, v in mydict.items()}

In [22]: mydict2
Out[22]: {'a': [1], 'b': [2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert Dictionary to Data Frame

```
col_dict_df = pd.Series(col_dict).to_frame('new_col').reset_index()
```

Give new name to  Column

```
col_dict_df.columns = ['col1', 'col2']
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have a dictionary you can turn it into a pandas data frame with the following line of code:

```
pd.DataFrame({"key": d.keys(), "value": d.values()})
```

Comment: It works, but IMHO it doesn't make much sense 
<code>
    `
    <!-- language: lang-py -->
    fruits_count = defaultdict(int)
    fruits_count["apples"] = 10
    fruits_count["bananas"] = 21
    pd.DataFrame({"key" : fruits_count.keys(), "value" :     fruits_count.values()})
    Out: 
                     key     value
    0  (bananas, apples)  (21, 10)
    1  (bananas, apples)  (21, 10)
<code>

Answer (score -3):

Just pass the dict on a list:

```
a = 2
b = 3
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'A':a,'B':b}])
```