# Combining two Series into a DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, series, dataframe

I have two Series `s1` and `s2` with the same (non-consecutive) indices. How do I combine `s1` and `s2` to being two columns in a DataFrame and keep one of the indices as a third column?

Answer (score 586, accepted):

I think [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.merge.concat.html) is a nice way to do this. If they are present it uses the name attributes of the Series as the columns (otherwise it simply numbers them):

```
In [1]: s1 = pd.Series([1, 2], index=['A', 'B'], name='s1')

In [2]: s2 = pd.Series([3, 4], index=['A', 'B'], name='s2')

In [3]: pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)
Out[3]:
   s1  s2
A   1   3
B   2   4

In [4]: pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1).reset_index()
Out[4]:
  index  s1  s2
0     A   1   3
1     B   2   4
```

*Note: This extends to more than 2 Series.*

Comment: this actually avoids copying too (as compared to the dict solution)

Comment: In one instance, it seems to be telling me 'ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()' - any ideas?

Comment: @user7289 not sure where that would come from, could you ask this as another question?

Comment: @AndyHayden: what if there are duplicates along one or both indexes?

Comment: @Mannaggia hmmmm, I think it depends what you want the answer to be... something with merge: `pd.merge(s1.reset_index(), s2.reset_index(), how='outer')` ?

Comment: @Jeff From the pandas website
"It is worth noting however, that concat (and therefore append) makes a full copy of the data, and that constantly reusing this function can create a signifcant performance hit. If you need to use the operation over several datasets, use a list comprehension."

Comment: @dafinguzman what "constantly reusing this function" means is that you should prefer doing the concat **once** `pd.concat([list_of_dataframes])` vs concating many times `new_df = pd.DataFrame(); for df in list_of_dsf: new_df = pd.concat([new_df, df])` or similar.

Comment: what happens if the one of the series already exists in a dataframe, but I then try to concat that series that has values that are greater in length then the previous series

Comment: It should do an outer join in that case, BUT you may want to be more specific in cases like this (to use a join/merge). See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: You really ought to point out that this grammar is an extremely special case when the two series share the same index - otherwise you're hiding a lot of complexity under the hood.

Answer (score 78):

You can use `to_frame` if both have the same indexes.

**>= `v0.23`**

```
a.to_frame().join(b)
```

**< `v0.23`**

```
a.to_frame().join(b.to_frame())
```

Comment: Maybe this would be more appropriate: a.to_frame(name = 'a').join(b.to_frame(name='b'))

Answer (score 40):

Pandas will automatically align these passed in series and create the joint index
They happen to be the same here. `reset_index` moves the index to a column.

```
In [2]: s1 = Series(randn(5),index=[1,2,4,5,6])

In [4]: s2 = Series(randn(5),index=[1,2,4,5,6])

In [8]: DataFrame(dict(s1 = s1, s2 = s2)).reset_index()
Out[8]: 
   index        s1        s2
0      1 -0.176143  0.128635
1      2 -1.286470  0.908497
2      4 -0.995881  0.528050
3      5  0.402241  0.458870
4      6  0.380457  0.072251
```

Comment: np.random.randn(5)

Answer (score 21):

Example code:

```
a = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index=[7,2,8,9])
b = pd.Series([5,6,7,8], index=[7,2,8,9])
data = pd.DataFrame({'a': a,'b':b, 'idx_col':a.index})
```

Pandas allows you to create a `DataFrame` from a `dict` with `Series` as the values and the column names as the keys. When it finds a `Series` as a value, it uses the `Series` index as part of the `DataFrame` index. This data alignment is one of the main perks of Pandas. Consequently, unless you have other needs, the freshly created `DataFrame` has duplicated value. In the above example, `data['idx_col']` has the same data as `data.index`.

Answer (score 21):

If I may answer this.

The fundamentals behind converting series to data frame is to understand that

***1. At conceptual level, every column in data frame is a series.***

***2. And, every column name is a key name that maps to a series.***

If you keep above two concepts in mind, you can think of many ways to convert series to data frame.
One easy solution will be like this:

Create two series here

```
import pandas as pd

series_1 = pd.Series(list(range(10)))

series_2 = pd.Series(list(range(20,30)))
```

Create an empty data frame with just desired column names

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Column_name#1', 'Column_name#1'])
```

Put series value inside data frame using mapping concept

```
df['Column_name#1'] = series_1

df['Column_name#2'] = series_2
```

Check results now

```
df.head(5)
```

Answer (score 10):

Not sure I fully understand your question, but is this what you want to do?

```
pd.DataFrame(data=dict(s1=s1, s2=s2), index=s1.index)
```

(`index=s1.index` is not even necessary here)

Answer (score 8):

A simplification of the solution based on `join()`:

```
df = a.to_frame().join(b)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are trying to join Series of equal length but their indexes don't match (which is a common scenario), then concatenating them will generate NAs wherever they don't match.

```py
x = pd.Series({'a':1,'b':2,})
y = pd.Series({'d':4,'e':5})
pd.concat([x,y],axis=1)

#Output (I've added column names for clarity)
Index   x    y
a      1.0  NaN
b      2.0  NaN
d      NaN  4.0
e      NaN  5.0
```

Assuming that you don't care if the indexes match, the solution is to reindex both Series before concatenating them.  If `drop=False`, which is the default, then Pandas will save the old index in a column of the new dataframe (the indexes are dropped here for simplicity).

```py
pd.concat([x.reset_index(drop=True),y.reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)

#Output (column names added):
Index   x   y
0       1   4
1       2   5
```

Answer (score 1):

I used pandas to convert my numpy array or iseries to an dataframe then added and additional the additional column by key as 'prediction'. If you need dataframe converted back to a list then use values.tolist()

```
output=pd.DataFrame(X_test)
output['prediction']=y_pred

list=output.values.tolist()
```