# Trying to join two series, having possibly index issues

Tags: pandas, join

I have two series which have the same index.  Their basic format is

a =

```
Index Data_Value
date1  3
date2  56
.      .
.      .
.      .
```

b =

```
Index Data_Value
date1  22
date2  34
.      . 
.      .
.      .
```

Based on previous question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062135/combining-two-series-into-a-dataframe-in-pandas), I am trying to join them using:

```
a.to_frame().join(b.to_frame())
```

but I get the error:

```
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['Data_Value'], dtype='object')
```

I thought it might be an issue with the field name,because 'b.name' returns 'Data_Value', so I tried:

a.to_frame().join(b.to_frame(),on='Data_Value' )
but still the same error.

Any guidance very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

There is same names, simpliest is change it in [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
c = a.to_frame('a').join(b.to_frame('b'))
print (c)
        a   b
Index        
date1   3  22
date2  56  34
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to both value same name using `concat`

```
pd.concat([a,b],1)
Out[129]: 
       Data_Value  Data_Value
Index                        
date1           3          22
date2          56          34
```

Comment: what is the 1 achieving here please?

Comment: @ZakS axis=1 which direction bind the data