# Seaborn boxplot showing number on x-axis, not the name of pd.Series object

Tags: python, seaborn

Problem : I want my seaborn boxplot to show names of pd.Series(Group A, Group B) 
 on X axis, but it only shows number. The number 0 for the first pd.Series, and 1 for the next pd.Series object.

My codes are as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

Group_A=pd.Series([26,21,22,26,19,22,26,25,24,21,23,23,18,29,22])
Group_B=pd.Series([18,23,21,20,20,29,20,16,20,26,21,25,17,18,19])

sns.set(style="whitegrid")
ax=sns.boxplot(data=[Group_A, Group_B], palette='Set2')
```

Result :

[image: Please click here to see the image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the two series into a dataframe. There are [a lot of options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062135/combining-two-series-into-a-dataframe-in-pandas) to do so, here is one example which will produce nice names:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Group_A=pd.Series([26,21,22,26,19,22,26,25,24,21,23,23,18,29,22])
Group_B=pd.Series([18,23,21,20,20,29,20,16,20,26,21,25,17,18,19])
df = pd.DataFrame({"ColumnA" : Group_A, "ColumnB" : Group_B})

sns.set(style="whitegrid")
ax=sns.boxplot(data=df , palette='Set2')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I practice R exercises with Python and it takes much more lines to do the same thing on Python.. Thank you for your kind answer :D