# How to append a dataframe to another dataframe when indexes are not existed, fill the nan values when they do?

Tags: python, pandas

Firstly, I have an empty dataframe `df` with two columns `['A','B']` and two series `s1, s2` which have the same index, What I want to do is to append two series to the dataframe in two steps:
At first, it's empty

```
 A  B
```

Two series are:

```
s1:
2019-10-08  0.00496 
2019-10-09  0.00491 
s2:
2019-10-08  0.00116 
2019-10-09  0.00111
```

Then I want to append a Series `s1`, which named `'1'`

```
df['A'] = df['A'].append(s1)
```

My Dataframe now is like

```
                A    B
2019-10-08  0.00496 NaN
2019-10-09  0.00491 NaN
```

When I do

```
df['B'] = df['B'].append(s2)
```

it says `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`
Anyways to get around it?

The desired result is

```
 A    B
2019-10-08  0.00496 0.00116
2019-10-09  0.00491 0.00111
```

It has to assign by indexes with the same appending operations, because `s1, s2` indexes might not be exactly the same, and there is no guarantee which appending operation comes first

Comment: @jezrael can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an outer join :

```py
df = s1.to_frame(name = 'A').join(s2.to_frame(name='B'), how='outer')
```

See comment on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35616082/9892619)