# Panda returning NaN values when I print inline 2 columns extracted from 2 different csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am extracting 2 columns from 2 different CSV with panda and I would like to print the 2 columns extracted.

I have no problems printing out each column separately, but when I want to print the 2 columns inline, it returns NaN values instead of float.

To be clearer, here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd

col_list = ["ID",]
df = pd.read_csv("waterproofposters.csv", usecols=col_list)

col_list = ["Regular price",]
dg = pd.read_csv("tempwaterproofposters.csv", usecols=col_list,)

dh = pd.DataFrame((df)|(dg))

print (df)
Output: 
          ID
     0    23770.0
     1    23771.0
     2    23772.0
     3    23773.0
     4    23774.0

print (dg)
Output: 
        Regular price
     0          25.79
     1          40.19
     2          55.19
     3          69.59

print (dh)
Output:
          ID  Regular price
     0   NaN            NaN
     1   NaN            NaN
     2   NaN            NaN
     3   NaN            NaN
     4   NaN            NaN
```

Wanted output:

```
     ID          Regular price
0    23770.0      25.79
1    23771.0      40.19
2    23772.0      55.19
3    23773.0      69.59
4    23774.0      NaN or null
```

Comment: Are you trying to merge two dataframes, or two series into a dataframe ? Would this answer help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062135/combining-two-series-into-a-dataframe-in-pandas ?

Comment: @GuitarExtended The quoted link is for combining 2 series.  Here is 2 dataframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to join the 2 dataframes vertically,  instead of `dh = pd.DataFrame((df)|(dg))`

```
dh = df.join(dg)
```

Result:

```
print(dh)

        ID  Regular price
0  23770.0          25.79
1  23771.0          40.19
2  23772.0          55.19
3  23773.0          69.59
4  23774.0            NaN
```

Comment: dh = df.join(dg) worked perfectly. Thank you very much. You've made my day, I would like to upvote your contribution but I can't because I'm a new contributor

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have just marked ✓ your answer.