# pandas read_json: "If using all scalar values, you must pass an index"

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have some difficulty in importing a JSON file with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
map_index_to_word = pd.read_json('people_wiki_map_index_to_word.json')
```

This is the  error that I get:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

The file structure is simplified like this:

```
{"biennials": 522004, "lb915": 116290, "shatzky": 127647, "woode": 174106, "damfunk": 133206, "nualart": 153444, "hatefillot": 164111, "missionborn": 261765, "yeardescribed": 161075, "theoryhe": 521685}
```

It is from the machine learning course of University of Washington on Coursera. You can find the file [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/ml-clustering-and-retrieval/supplement/gJSfc/choosing-features-and-metrics-for-nearest-neighbor-search).

Comment: This is much more a pandas question than it it a JSON question -- you wouldn't have this specific error in any context that *didn't* involve pandas, but you **can** get this specific error without JSON being involved.

Comment: See for instance, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839973/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-values-in-variables -- a question with the same error, but no JSON involved.

Comment: look like you are taking the ML courses from Emily :)

Comment: It is expecting a list. So if you do like this will work.  `pd.DataFrame([{"biennials": 522004, "lb915": 116290}])`.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Try

```
ser = pd.read_json('people_wiki_map_index_to_word.json', typ='series')
```

That file only contains key value pairs where values are scalars. You can convert it to a dataframe with `ser.to_frame('count')`.

You can also do something like this:

```
import json
with open('people_wiki_map_index_to_word.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Now data is a dictionary. You can pass it to a dataframe constructor like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'count': data})
```

Answer (score 20):

You can do as @ayhan mention which will give you a column base format

[image: Method 1]

**Or you can enclose the object in [ ] ([source](https://interviewbubble.com/valueerror-if-using-all-scalar-values-you-must-pass-an-index/)) as shown below to give you a row format that will be convenient if you are loading multiple values and planing on using matrix for your machine learning models.**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([data])
```

[image: Method 2]

Answer (score 6):

I think what is happening is that the data in

```
map_index_to_word = pd.read_json('people_wiki_map_index_to_word.json')
```

is being read as a string instead of a json

```
{"biennials": 522004, "lb915": 116290, "shatzky": 127647, "woode": 174106, "damfunk": 133206, "nualart": 153444, "hatefillot": 164111, "missionborn": 261765, "yeardescribed": 161075, "theoryhe": 521685}
```

is actually

```
'{"biennials": 522004, "lb915": 116290, "shatzky": 127647, "woode": 174106, "damfunk": 133206, "nualart": 153444, "hatefillot": 164111, "missionborn": 261765, "yeardescribed": 161075, "theoryhe": 521685}'
```

Since a string is a scalar, it wants you to load it as a json, you have to convert it to a dict which is exactly what the other response is doing

The best way is to do a json loads on the string to convert it to a dict and load it into pandas

```
myfile=f.read()
jsonData=json.loads(myfile)
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: thanks for the explaination, I have been looking for the reason for some time already.

Answer (score 5):

```
{
"biennials": 522004,
"lb915": 116290
}

df = pd.read_json('values.json')
```

As pd.read_json expects a list

```
{
"biennials": [522004],
"lb915": [116290]
}
```

for a particular key, it returns an error saying

**If using all scalar values, you must pass an index.**

So you can resolve this by specifying 'typ' arg in pd.read_json

```
map_index_to_word = pd.read_json('Datasets/people_wiki_map_index_to_word.json', typ='dictionary')
```

Comment: `typ='dictionary'` was what i needed

Answer (score 3):

For newer pandas, 0.19.0 and later, use the lines parameter, set it to True.
The file is read as a json object per line.

```
import pandas as pd
map_index_to_word = pd.read_json('people_wiki_map_index_to_word.json', lines=True)
```

If fixed the following errors I encountered especially when some of the json files have only one value:

1. ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
2. JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
3. ValueError: Trailing data

Answer (score 1):

For example
**cat values.json**

```
{
name: "Snow",
age: "31"
}

df = pd.read_json('values.json')
```

Chances are you might end up with this
Error: **if using all scalar values, you must pass an index**

Pandas looks up for a list or dictionary in the value. Something like
**cat values.json**

```
{
name: ["Snow"],
age: ["31"]
}
```

So try doing this. Later on to convert to html tohtml()

```
df = pd.DataFrame([pd.read_json(report_file,  typ='series')])
result = df.to_html()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by converting it into an array like so

```
[{"biennials": 522004, "lb915": 116290, "shatzky": 127647, "woode": 174106, "damfunk": 133206, "nualart": 153444, "hatefillot": 164111, "missionborn": 261765, "yeardescribed": 161075, "theoryhe": 521685}]
```

Answer (score 0):

### A complete working example

First I save the data you posted in a json file:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

json_data = {"biennials": 522004, "lb915": 116290, "shatzky": 127647,
             "woode": 174106, "damfunk": 133206, "nualart": 153444,
             "hatefillot": 164111, "missionborn": 261765,
             "yeardescribed": 161075, "theoryhe": 521685}

save_fpath = '/content/sample_file.json'
with open(save_fpath, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(json_data, f)
```

Then, using the [method proposed by obiradaniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72949543/11764049), it's possible to obtain a pandas dataframe through this code:

```
sample_df = pd.read_json(save_fpath, lines=True).T.reset_index()
sample_df.columns = ['col_1', 'col_2']
sample_df
```

Basically, the keys of the `json_data` dictionary are transformed into column names using `lines=True`. For this reason I then transpose the dataframe (column names become index names) and then reset the index. Finally, new column names are assigned.

It's possible to skip the transposition step using the `orient` argument. In this way, the keys of the `json_data` dict are read from the beginning as index names. Here is an example using that:

```
sample_df = pd.read_json(save_fpath, orient='index').reset_index()
sample_df.columns = ['col_1', 'col_2']
sample_df
```

In both ways, the resulting dataframe is the following:

|  | col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | biennials | 522004 |
| 1 | lb915 | 116290 |
| 2 | shatzky | 127647 |
| 3 | woode | 174106 |
| 4 | damfunk | 133206 |
| 5 | nualart | 153444 |
| 6 | hatefillot | 164111 |
| 7 | missionborn | 261765 |
| 8 | yeardescribed | 161075 |
| 9 | theoryhe | 521685 |