# Python: Pandas occurred ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Tags: python, pandas

I try to read an url with json data but return

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

How to eliminate the error?
My code is

```
url = 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/stats'
data = pd.read_json(url)
```

Comment: Did you do a  search with that that error and try to relate the results to your circumstances?  You really haven't provided enough information.  Please take the time to read [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: I try the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380795/pandas-read-json-if-using-all-scalar-values-you-must-pass-an-index but still return same error