# Transform json files in directory in parquet files with python & pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, parquet

I'm struggling with converting of local json files into parquet files. Each file should be converted with pandas to a parquet file and save it, so i have the same amount of files, just as parquets.

I looped through my directory and became a list of all my json files existing and put them into a pandas dataframe.

```
path = 'trackingdata/'

df = list()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
   for name in files:
      df.append(os.path.join(root, name))
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Is it better to loop trough the dataframe now and transform each file with

```
df.to_parquet('trackingdata.parquet')
```

or would it be better to write the transformation into the code above after looping through the dir? And how can i transform each of the files to parquet without joining all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about defining a json_to_parquet converter:

```
def json_to_parquet(filepath):
    df = pd.read_json(filepath, typ='series').to_frame("name")
    parquet_file = filepath.split(".")[0] + ".parquet"
    df.to_parquet(parquet_file)
```

Depending on how your json is formatted you may need to change the read_json line and/or use the tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380795/pandas-read-json-if-using-all-scalar-values-you-must-pass-an-index)

Then just processing each file one at at time:

```
path = 'trackingdata/'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        json_to_parquet(os.path.join(root, name))
```