# Error message when appending data to pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, append

Can someone give me a hand with this:

I created a loop to append successive intervals of historical price data from Coinbase.

My loop iterates successfully a few times then crashes.

Error message (under data_temp code line):

"ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index"

```py
days = 10
end = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
start = end - timedelta(days=days)
data_price = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(1,50):
    print(start)
    print(end)
    data_temp = pd.DataFrame(public_client.get_product_historic_rates(product_id='BTC-USD', granularity=3600, start=start, end=end))
    data_price = data_price.append(data_temp)
    end = start
    start = end - timedelta(days=days)
```

Would love to understand how to fix this and why this is happening in the first place.

Thank you!

Here's the full trace:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\coinbase_bot.py", line 46, in 
    data_temp = pd.DataFrame(public_client.get_product_historic_rates(product_id='BTC-USD', granularity=3600, start=start, end=end))
  File "D:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 411, in **init**
    mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 257, in init_dict
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 77, in arrays_to_mgr
    index = extract_index(arrays)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 358, in extract_index
    raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Here's json returned via simple url call:

[[1454716800,370.05,384.54,384.44,375.44,6276.66473729],[1454630400,382.99,389.36,387.99,384.5,7443.92933224],[1454544000,368.74,390.63,368.87,387.99,8887.7572324],[1454457600,365.63,373.01,372.93,368.87,7147.95657328],[1454371200,371.17,374.41,371.33,372.93,6856.21815799],[1454284800,366.26,379,367.89,371.33,7931.22922922],[1454198400,365,382.5,378.46,367.95,5506.77681302]]

Very similar to this user's issue but cannot put my finger on it:
[When attempting to merge multiple dataframes, how to resolve "ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650193/when-attempting-to-merge-multiple-dataframes-how-to-resolve-valueerror-if-usi)

Comment: Hi please add some example data and a the full trace for that error

Comment: updated the post with the full error trace and sample json data obtained from url call.  i'm using an python lib which is wrapping the url calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- Hi DashOfProgramming,

Your problem is that the *data_temp* is initialised with only a single row and pandas requires you to provide it with an index for that.

The following snippet should resolve this. I replaced your API call with a simple dictionary that resembles what I would expect the API to return and used *i* as index for the dataframe (this has the advantage that you can keep track as well):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

days = 10
end = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
start = end - timedelta(days=days)
data_price = pd.DataFrame()

temp_dict = {'start': '2019-09-30', 'end': '2019-10-01', 'price': '-111.0928', 
'currency': 'USD'}

for i in range(1,50):
  print(start)
  print(end)
  data_temp = pd.DataFrame(temp_dict, index=[i])
  data_price = data_price.append(data_temp)
  end = start
  start = end - timedelta(days=days)

print(data_price)
```

---

EDIT

Just saw that your API output is a nested list. pd.DataFrame() thinks the list is only one row, because it's nested. I suggest you store your columns in a separate variable and then do this:

```
cols = ['ts', 'low', 'high', 'open', 'close', 'sth_else']

v = [[...], [...], [...]] # your list of lists

data_temp = pd.DataFrame.from_records(v, columns=cols)
```

Comment: What's confusing me with all of this that if I use a range of 5 instead of 50 when I start the for loop everything works great; I get panda frame with the expected number of rows and columns.  I'll try your EDITED solution and report back shortly.  Thanks.

Comment: ok i just noticed that i'm retrieving empty data frames later on ... that's prob what's causing all these issues

Comment: just add an additional check if len(values) > 0 add dataframe else continue

Comment: Thx for your help Joe.  I was calling the API too quickly.  Added a one sec sleep between each loop and that resolved the issue.

Comment: @DashOfProgramming no problem! Could have actually thought of that myself too.. built sth similar before. Although with a PUSH API and asyncio listeners. Good Luck!