# Converting a Dict having blank list (Values) to a df

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I'm a neophyte to pandas and have been struggling to convert a Dict to a df using `pd.DataFrame(Dict)`. Here's further detail: This Dict is part of a for loop that in every iteration reads in a new input file. As a result, Dict Values (lists) update every time and take different List sizes. The problem is, my code fails to execute `pd.DataFrame(Dict)` once Dict contains blank lists (Values) for all Keys and spits out: "ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index"

```
Dict = {'Title': [],
'Organization': [],
'City': [],
'Company': []}
```

Could anybody shed some light on this? Thanks a million in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Running your dictionary example through the `pd.DataFrame(Dict)` command does not give me any errors, I just get an empty DataFrame.  And that's how it should be, as those empty lists you have as values are not scalars, they are iterables.  This `ValueError` shows up when all values are in fact scalars, e.g., integers/floats/strings.  If you just convert those scalars into iterables, such as empty lists or lists each containing one element (e.g., `['New York']`), you should not get any errors.

Per this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839973/constructing-pandas-dataframe-from-values-in-variables-gives-valueerror-if-usi), there are many suggested ways to handle this error when you actually have scalars, such as actually passing an index to `pd.DataFrame()` as a list, as requested by the error message.  You just need to make the size of that index list the same as the number of elements you are feeding to the DataFrame.