# How to split single column with list of dictionaries into multiple columns in pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

Currently playing around with some data from an API using pandas, but one area I'm particularly interested in seems to be crammed into one column as a list of dictionaries.

How can I split this column out into four new columns?

Currently:

```
chip_plays
__________
[{"chip_name":"bboost",
"num_played":114585},
{"chip_name":"freehit",
"num_played":89437},
{"chip_name":"wildcard",
"num_played":263066},
{"chip_name":"3xc",
"num_played":216711}]

[{"chip_name":"bboost",
"num_played":79069},
{"chip_name":"freehit",
"num_played":41897},
{"chip_name":"wildcard",
"num_played":103086},
{"chip_name":"3xc",
"num_played":74713}]

...
```

Desired outcome:

```
bboost     freehit     wildcard     3xc
_________________________________________
114585     89437       263066       216711
79069      41897       103086       74713
...
```

In case it's useful, the api link is: https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/

Screenshot of dataframe:
https://share.getcloudapp.com/o0u8yYZn

Comment: Hello @lookofdisdain. Welcome to S.O. Please provide some code with what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

`pivot_table` does the job:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"chip_name":"bboost",
"num_played":114585},
{"chip_name":"freehit",
"num_played":89437},
{"chip_name":"wildcard",
"num_played":263066},
{"chip_name":"3xc",
"num_played":216711}])

print(pd.pivot_table(df, values='num_played', columns='chip_name'))
chip_name      3xc  bboost  freehit  wildcard
num_played  216711  114585    89437    263066
```

Comment: Would that work over multiple rows though? [screenshot] (https://share.getcloudapp.com/o0u8yYZn)

Comment: you can set the `values` as the list of desired rows

Answer (score 0):

## PLEASE SEE UPDATE

The below example provides the output you are looking for given the response provided in your original question.

It creates the df you want by way of a dictionary comprehension which:

- Iterates across the list (`response`)
- Inserts each `"chip_name"` value as a key
- Attributes a list containing the corresponding `"num_played"` value to each key

The resultant dictionary (`data`) is then passed as an argument to the `pd.DataFrame()` to create your desired output.

```py
import pandas as pd

response = [{"chip_name":"bboost",
"num_played":114585},
{"chip_name":"freehit",
"num_played":89437},
{"chip_name":"wildcard",
"num_played":263066},
{"chip_name":"3xc",
"num_played":216711}]

data = { i['chip_name']: [i['num_played']] for i in response} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Will give you the following `df`.

```
   bboost  freehit  wildcard     3xc
0  114585    89437    263066  216711
```

*NOTE*: The value passed doesn't necessarily have to be within a list, however if it isn't see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839973/constructing-pandas-dataframe-from-values-in-variables-gives-valueerror-if-usi) for information about passing scalar values to `pd.DataFrame()`.

### UPDATE

Below example works for question following OP update to question. Fairly self explanatory:

- Defines column names based on response content
- Creates empty `df` with column names
- Iterates across response list
- Extracts row data using dictionary comprehension as in original answer
- Create new `df` (`temp`) and append to existing to add new rows

```py
import pandas as pd

response = [
    [{"chip_name":"bboost",
    "num_played":114585},
    {"chip_name":"freehit",
    "num_played":89437},
    {"chip_name":"wildcard",
    "num_played":263066},
    {"chip_name":"3xc",
    "num_played":216711}],

    [{"chip_name":"bboost",
    "num_played":79069},
    {"chip_name":"freehit",
    "num_played":41897},
    {"chip_name":"wildcard",
    "num_played":103086},
    {"chip_name":"3xc",
    "num_played":74713}]
]

columns = ['bboost', 'freehit', 'wildcard', '3xc']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for i in response:
    data = { j['chip_name']: [j['num_played']] for j in i }
    temp = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
    df = df.append(temp, ignore_index=True)
```

`df` looks like this:

```
   bboost freehit wildcard     3xc
0  114585   89437   263066  216711
1   79069   41897   103086   74713
```

Will work fine with variable response length.

*NOTE*: Seems there may be a typo on part of OP in updated question. My update works under the assumption that the response is a list of lists containing single item dictionaries as this seems to make the most sense based on example given.

Comment: Is it possible to use that to iterate through the rows?

Comment: @lookofdisdain updated based on your question edit(s)

Comment: thank you, worked perfectly. Sorry for any confusion with the original question

Comment: No worries, all part of the experience ;) Glad this has helped