# Creating pandas DataFrame from np.ndarrays returns 'If using all scalar values, you must pass an index'

Tags: python, pandas

I have two numpy.ndarrays: `Y_train` and `Y_pred_train`. Both are of the shape (799, 1).

The following line of code returns an exception 'If using all scalar values, you must pass an index':

```
df_train = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Y_Actual_train' : Y_train, 'Y_Pred_train' : Y_pred_train})
```

But these arrays are not scallars or what. I don't understand.

Comment: `{'Y_Actual_train' : Y_train.squeeze(), ...`

Comment: Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constructing pandas DataFrame from values in variables gives "ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839973/constructing-pandas-dataframe-from-values-in-variables-gives-valueerror-if-usi)