# How do I count unique words in a list/set in python that is kind of nested/complicated

Tags: python, counting

I am trying to count unique words in a list/set (or whatever its called) that looks something like this:

```
names = [[], [], [], [], [], [['John ', 'John '], ['Peter ']], [], [], [], [['Morgan']], [], [], []]
```

(In case you need to know, this list was formed as a result of a match function that looks for a list of  names in word documents in a directory on my computer. The empty spaces you see are documents that matched nothing)

So far I have tried

```
names1 = set(names)
len (names1)
```

And

```
Counter(names).keys() 
Counter(names).values()
```

but neither worked. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Here is a tip: recursively go into each list and count the words.

Comment: One option would be to flatten the list of lists of lists with techniques from the old question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists, then perform the count on the flattened list.

Comment: @JaideepShekhar there are words that repeat across lists. How do I ensure that the repetition is taken into account

Comment: I don't understand why you expect that to cause a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This came to my mind:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int) # default int is 0
names = [[], [], [], [], [], [['John ', 'John '], ['Peter ']], [], [], [], [['Morgan']], [], [], []]

def find(ele):
    if isinstance(ele, str):
        d[ele] += 1
    
    if isinstance(ele, list):
        for e in ele:
            find(e)
    
find(names)
print(d) # {'John ': 2, 'Peter ': 1, 'Morgan': 1}
```

It's a recursive function that checks if it's a list. If it is, then it checks if it's not empty and proceeds to call itself again. Otherwise, it just returns. If it finds a string, it simply adds itself to the dictionary.

Comment: This is a good answer, but your `if len(ele) > 0..else` is not necessary.  If the length is zero, the for loop will simply not execute.

Comment: Good point. Didn't think it through and wanted to make everything as explicit as possible for the OP - or for any question/answer discussion.

Comment: @lionbigcat Thankyou that worked. How do I make it case insensitive though. It is currently listing Morgan and MORGAN as two different words.

Comment: @Eisenheim just convert it all to lowercase.

Comment: @Eisenheim, `d[ele.lower()] += 1`

Comment: @lionbigcat One more thing. I am trying to write it to excel using `pd.DataFrame(d)  count.to_excel(writerrr, sheet_name='count', index=False)` but it throws this error: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: @Eisenheim take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17840195/8721930. Googling error msgs, will more often than not, yield good results.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at making the comment by @Jaideep Shekhar more explicit, and also including your original use of the Counter object:

```
from collections import Counter

wordcount_dict = Counter()

for elem in names:
    for namelist in elem:
        wordcount_dict += Counter(namelist)

print(len(wordcount_dict))
```

Comment: This solution doesn't handle nested lists.

Comment: That's true. I guess I took the OP's example too literally.

Comment: Actually, considering what he calls his data source, your interpretation probably is fine!   I don't think his search results would be nested any further.