# Getting Error: "ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index" when converting ndarray to pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

When transforming multiple `ndarray` to a `df` as per the code below

```
import  numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ls_a = ['TA', 'BAT', 'T']
xxx = ['xx', 'cc']

feature_no = len(ls_a)
windows_no = len(xxx)


sub_iti = np.repeat([['s1']], (feature_no * windows_no), axis=0).reshape(-1, 1)
tw = np.repeat([xxx], feature_no, axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)
col_iti = np.repeat([ls_a], windows_no, axis=0).reshape(-1, 1)

df=pd.DataFrame ({'sub_iti': sub_iti,'tw': tw,'col_iti': col_iti})
```

, the compiler return an error

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Based on [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839973/constructing-pandas-dataframe-from-values-in-variables-gives-valueerror-if-usi), the argument `index` was inputed as below

```
 df=pd.DataFrame (
             {'sub_iti': sub_iti,
              'tw': tw,
              'col_iti': col_iti},index=range(0,3*2) )
```

However, the compiler return diff rent error

> Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional

May I know how to address this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using ```pd.DataFrame.from_dict```? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @swagless_monk, but it return `ValueError: Must pass 2-d input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your `sub_iti, tw, col_iti` are 2D numpy arrays. However, when you do:

```
df=pd.DataFrame ({'sub_iti': sub_iti,
                   'tw': tw,
                   'col_iti': col_iti} )
```

Pandas expected them to be `1D` numpy arrays or lists, since that's how columns of a DataFrame should be. You can try:

```
df=pd.DataFrame ({'sub_iti': sub_iti.tolist(),
                 'tw': tw.tolist(),'col_iti': col_iti.tolist()})
```

Output:

```
  sub_iti    tw col_iti
0    [s1]  [xx]    [TA]
1    [s1]  [xx]   [BAT]
2    [s1]  [xx]     [T]
3    [s1]  [cc]    [TA]
4    [s1]  [cc]   [BAT]
5    [s1]  [cc]     [T]
```

But I do think that you should remove the lists inside each cell, and use `ravel()` instead of `tolist()`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame ({'sub_iti': sub_iti.ravel(),
                 'tw': tw.ravel(),'col_iti': col_iti.ravel()})
```

Output:

```
  sub_iti  tw col_iti
0      s1  xx      TA
1      s1  xx     BAT
2      s1  xx       T
3      s1  cc      TA
4      s1  cc     BAT
5      s1  cc       T
```

Comment: plus one on the ravel