# for loop in Pandas on returning limited items from list

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am reading in a JSON file contains all of the information coming from an API request. The file isn't very large, only about 200 items. I am attempting to loop through each item, store it as a pandas DataFrame, append it to a list, and concat the results into one DataFrame.

```
df_list = []
list_length = 53
for i in range(list_length):
  df = pd.DataFrame(contenders_list[i]).T.reset_index()
  df_list.append(df)

new_df = pd.concat(mylist)
new_df.head()
```

If I run this, it works. I have a DataFrame with the first 53 items from the JSON file. However, if I go above 53, like the actual length of the list, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass in an index
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Can't you just turn the original list directly into a dataframe, without a loop like this?

Comment: There must be something different in `contenders_list[53]`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839973/constructing-pandas-dataframe-from-values-in-variables-gives-valueerror-if-usi for the explanation of the error.

Comment: If that doesn't answer it for you, you'll need to show example elements of `contenders_list` that work and fail.

Comment: what is `mylist`?

Comment: Before creating the dataframe, `print(contenders_list[i])`. Now you know what fails.

Comment: And post the entire traceback so we see which line fails.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried loading the JSON as a pandas DataFrame yet? Pandas has a method called `read_json`, it converts your JSON into a pandas DF automatically. Have a look:

```py
from pandas import read_json

# If the files are in the same folder, then you can simply write 'filename.json'
dataframe_from_json = read_json('path/to/your.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the best method to create a Dataframe from a dictionary. Pandas is expecting the data values to be list values or dict values. According to the error raised, you are passing a **scalar value**. In that case, you also have to pass in the index.

let's say you do :

```
my_dict = {
  'a':'1',
  'b':'2',
  'c':'3'
}

# Convert dict to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict)
df
```

you should indeed receive the following error:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

But if you do :

```
my_dict = {
  'a':['1'],
  'b':['2'],
  'c':['3']
}

# Convert dict to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict)
df
```

It will not raise any error and output as follows :

```
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
```