# extract serpapi results to csv file

Tags: python, csv, google-maps

i want to scrap google map results using serpapi
here is the suggested code:
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

```
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "API_KEY",
  "engine": "google_maps",
  "q": "company",
  "google_domain": "google.com",
  "hl": "en",
  "ll": "@37.5393407,36.707705,11z",
  "type": "search"
}

client = GoogleSearch(params)

data = client.get_dict()

print('data',data)
```

this successfully extract the results

but i want to save them as a csv file to could be able to analyse them

how can i access details presented in data such as adresses or webpages and so on

Answer (score 0):

To save extracted data to CSV you can use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and [`to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method. Note that `pandas` needs a `list` to be passed to `DataFrame`.

If you'll be passing `dict`, you might encounter `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index` error. To solve it, you need to [add `index=[0]` to your `DataFrame`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17840195/15164646).

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import pandas as pd

params = {
  "api_key": "...",
  "engine": "google_maps",
  "q": "company",
  "google_domain": "google.com",
  "hl": "en",
  "ll": "@37.5393407,36.707705,11z",
  "type": "search"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

# access "local_results" or other data you need
df = pd.DataFrame(results["local_results"])

# index=false to drop default pandas row numbers
df.to_csv(f"google-maps-{params['q']}-data.csv", index=False)
```

CSV `google-maps-company-data.csv` output for `"local_results"`:

[image]

Let me know if you have any issues.