# Best way to initialize and fill an numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, initialization

I want to initialize and fill a `numpy` array. What is the best way?

This works as I expect:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.empty(3)
array([ -1.28822975e-231,  -1.73060252e-077,   2.23946712e-314])
```

But this doesn't:

```
>>> np.empty(3).fill(np.nan)
>>>
```

Nothing?

```
>>> type(np.empty(3))
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

It seems to me that the `np.empty()` call is returning the correct type of object, so I don't understand why `.fill()` is not working?

Assigning the result of `np.empty()` first works fine:

```
>>> a = np.empty(3)
>>> a.fill(np.nan)
>>> a
array([ nan,  nan,  nan])
```

Why do I need to assign to a variable in order to use `np.fill()`? Am I missing a better alternative?

Comment: "Why do I need to assign to a variable in order to use np.fill()? " For the same reason as with countless other methods, including standard library workhorses like `list.append`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[`np.fill`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.fill.html) modifies the array in-place, and returns `None`. Therefor, if you're assigning the result to a name, it gets a value of `None`.

An alternative is to use an expression which returns `nan`, e.g.:

```
a = np.empty(3) * np.nan
```

Comment: Note however that this will not work for generic values, for which @JoshAdel answer is better for NumPy 1.8+, while for earlier version `np.zeros(shape) + value` should be used. See my answer for timings.

Answer (score 44):

You could also try:

```
In [79]: np.full(3, np.nan)
Out[79]: array([ nan,  nan,  nan])
```

The pertinent doc:

```
Definition: np.full(shape, fill_value, dtype=None, order='C')
Docstring:
Return a new array of given shape and type, filled with `fill_value`.
```

Although I think this might be only available in numpy 1.8+

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. If you are in older versions, you would need to do np.zeros(3) + value

Answer (score 3):

I find this easy to remember:

```
numpy.array([numpy.nan]*3)
```

Out of curiosity, I timed it, and both [@JoshAdel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22414429/943773) and [@shx2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22414391/943773) are far faster than mine with large arrays.

```
In [34]: %timeit -n10000 numpy.array([numpy.nan]*10000)
10000 loops, best of 3: 273 µs per loop

In [35]: %timeit -n10000 numpy.empty(10000)* numpy.nan
10000 loops, best of 3: 6.5 µs per loop

In [36]: %timeit -n10000 numpy.full(10000, numpy.nan)
10000 loops, best of 3: 5.42 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for future reference, the multiplication by `np.nan` only works because of the mathematical properties of `np.nan`.
For a generic value `N`, one would need to use `np.ones() * N` mimicking the accepted answer, however, speed-wise, this is not a terribly good choice.

Best choice would be `np.full()` as already pointed out, and, if that is not available for you, `np.zeros() + N` seems to be a better choice than `np.ones() * N`, while `np.empty() + N` or `np.empty() * N` are simply not suitable. Note that `np.zeros() + N` will also work when `N` is `np.nan`.

```
%timeit x = np.full((1000, 1000, 10), 432.4)
8.19 ms ± 97.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit x = np.zeros((1000, 1000, 10)) + 432.4
9.86 ms ± 55.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit x = np.ones((1000, 1000, 10)) * 432.4
17.3 ms ± 104 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit x = np.array([432.4] * (1000 * 1000 * 10)).reshape((1000, 1000, 10))
316 ms ± 37.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind `None`, you can use:

```
a = np.empty(3, dtype=object)
```