# With numpy, what's the fastest way to generate an array from -n to n, excluding 0, being `n` an integer?

Tags: python, numpy

With numpy, what's the fastest way to generate an array from -n to n, excluding 0, being `n` an integer?

Follows one solution, but I am not sure this is the fastest:

```
n = 100000
np.concatenate((np.arange(-n, 0), np.arange(1, n+1)))
```

Comment: Hi @gmagno, please check my post. If you like it, please give me an upvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative approach is to create the range -n to n-1.  Then add 1 to the elements from zero.

```
def non_zero_range(n):
    # The 2nd argument to np.arange is exclusive so it should be n and not n-1
    a=np.arange(-n,n)
    a[n:]+=1
    return a

n=1000000
%timeit np.concatenate((np.arange(-n,0), np.arange(1,n+1)))
# 4.28 ms ± 9.46 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit non_zero_range(n)
# 2.84 ms ± 13.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I think the reduced response time is due to only creating one array, not three as in the concatenate approach.

Comment: Agreed; for simple operations like this, minimizing temporaries is what it is all about, as far as numpy performance is concerned.

Comment: Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

Thanks, everyone. I edited my post and updated new test time.

Interesting problem.

### Experiment

I did it in my jupyter-notebook. All of them used `numpy` API. You can conduct the experiment of the following code by yourself.

About time measurement in jupyter-notebook, please see: [Simple way to measure cell execution time in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565829/simple-way-to-measure-cell-execution-time-in-ipython-notebook)

#### Original `np.concatenate`

```
%%timeit 
n = 100000
t = np.concatenate((np.arange(-n, 0), np.arange(1, n+1)))

#175 µs ± 2.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

#### Sol 1. `np.delete`

```
%%timeit 
n = 100000
a = np.arange(-n, n+1)
b = np.delete(a, n)

# 179 µs ± 5.66 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

#### Sol 2. List comprehension + `np.arrary`

```
%%timeit
c = np.array([x for x in range(-n, n+1) if x != 0])

# 16.6 ms ± 693 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

#### Conclusion

There's no big difference between original and solution 1, but solution 2 is the worst among the three. I'm looking for faster solutions, too.

### Reference

For those who are:

interested in initialize and fill an numpy array

- [Best way to initialize and fill an numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414152/best-way-to-initialize-and-fill-an-numpy-array)

get confused of `is` vs `==`

- [The Difference Between “is” and “==” in Python](https://dbader.org/blog/difference-between-is-and-equals-in-python)

Comment: There isn't a need for downvotes though. If you feel that his proof may be lacking then please point out what's lacking. I don't see anything that's inherently wrong.

Comment: @kerwei: I think you've misunderstood. This answer is only timing **the statement** `n = 100000`. The array creation is not timed.

Comment: @Tomothy32 got it, I'll check it.

Comment: @user2357112 Oh yes, I get your point. I did miss that too lol

Comment: use `%%timeit` to use it on entire block

Comment: @WeiYuangHsu Thanks for editing, but I don't believe the timings have been updated.

Comment: @Hi user2357112, is there anything I missed?

Comment: @Tomothy32 I got you. Updated.

Comment: @kerwei If there's anything I haven't noticed, please leave a comment. Btw, thank you, guys.

Comment: Looks like the timing problems have been fixed.

Comment: Side note, `if x is not 0` is not the correct way to compare integers. `is` is not a replacement for `==`. Use `if x != 0` or simply `if x`.