# Create columns in a large data frame based on another columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with over 60 thousand names of companies. I have this simplification of the data frame.

```
print dm


      COMPANY  ID  CUSIP
    0      AB   0     33
    1      CD   0     33
    2      LM   0     33
    3      NT   1     34
    4      ET   1     34
    5      RY   1     35
    6      EU   3     36
    7      EY   3     37
```

I would like to create a new column based on the values of ID and CUSIP

```
   COMPANY  ID  CUSIP    NEW ID
0      AB   0     33         1
1      CD   0     33         1 
2      LM   0     33         1
3      NT   1     34         2
4      ET   1     34         2 
5      RY   1     35         3
6      EU   3     36         4
7      EY   3     37         5
```

As you can see, for eache value of ID, if the value of CUSIP is different the value of the new ID is the previous value plus 1. Also, for each change of CUSIP, the value of ID is the previous value plus one.

My question is I would like to know a code which creates the new column based on the conditions recently explained using pandas. Any ideas?

Comment: could you clearly state your question?

Comment: My question is I would like to know a code which creates the new column.

Comment: [Possible duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas).  Summarized `df['new_column'] = new_column`

Comment: It's not a duplicated at all. The process to create the new column is totaly different!

Comment: you create a new column and then set the values according to the rules you described. Sounds like exactly what you are looking for...no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `factorize`:

```
In [30]: pd.factorize(df.CUSIP)
Out[30]: (array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([33, 34, 35, 36, 37]))

In [31]: values, labels = pd.factorize(df.CUSIP)

In [32]: df['NEW_ID'] = values

In [33]: df
Out[33]: 
  COMPANY  ID  CUSIP  NEW_ID
0      AB   0     33       0
1      CD   0     33       0
2      LM   0     33       0
3      NT   1     34       1
4      ET   1     34       1
5      RY   1     35       2
6      EU   3     36       3
7      EY   3     37       4

[8 rows x 4 columns]
```

add 1 to values to get your desired output, but 0 based indexing is more pythonic.