# Rpy2 and Pandas: join output from predict to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, r, pandas, random-forest, rpy2

I am using the `randomForest` library in R via `RPy2`. I would like to pass back the values calculated using the `caret` `predict` method and join them to the original `pandas` dataframe.  See example below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
r = robjects.r
r.library("randomForest")
r.library("caret")

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(100, 10), columns=["a{}".format(i) for i in range(10)])
df["b"] = ['a' if x < 0.5 else 'b' for x in np.random.sample(size=100)]
train = df.ix[df.a0 < .75]
withheld = df.ix[df.a0 >= .75]

rf = r.randomForest(robjects.Formula('b ~ .'), data=train)
pr = r.predict(rf, withheld)
print pr.rx()
```

Which returns

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
 a  a  b  b  b  a  a  a  a  b  a  a  a  a  a  b  a  a  a  a 
Levels: a b
```

But how can `join` this to the `withheld` dataframe or compare to the original values?

I have tried this:

```
import pandas.rpy.common as com
com.convert_robj(pr)
```

But this returns a dictionary where the keys are strings. I guess there is a work around of `withheld.reset_index()` and then converting the dict keys to integers and then joining the two but there must be a simpler way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a pull-request that adds R factor to Pandas Categorical functionality](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/9187)
to Pandas. It has not yet been merged into the Pandas master branch. When it is,

```
import pandas.rpy.common as rcom
rcom.convert_robj(pr)
```

will convert `pr` to a Pandas Categorical.
Until then, you can use as a workaround:

```
def convert_factor(obj):
    """
    Taken from jseabold's PR: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/9187
    """
    ordered = r["is.ordered"](obj)[0]
    categories = list(obj.levels)
    codes = np.asarray(obj) - 1  # zero-based indexing
    values = pd.Categorical.from_codes(codes, categories=categories,
                                       ordered=ordered)
    return values
```

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
r = robjects.r
r.library("randomForest")
r.library("caret")

def convert_factor(obj):
    """
    Taken from jseabold's PR: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/9187
    """
    ordered = r["is.ordered"](obj)[0]
    categories = list(obj.levels)
    codes = np.asarray(obj) - 1  # zero-based indexing
    values = pd.Categorical.from_codes(codes, categories=categories,
                                       ordered=ordered)
    return values


df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(100, 10), 
                  columns=["a{}".format(i) for i in range(10)])
df["b"] = ['a' if x < 0.5 else 'b' for x in np.random.sample(size=100)]
train = df.ix[df.a0 < .75]
withheld = df.ix[df.a0 >= .75]

rf = r.randomForest(robjects.Formula('b ~ .'), data=train)
pr = convert_factor(r.predict(rf, withheld))

withheld['pr'] = pr
print(withheld)
```

Answer (score 1):

The R object `pr` returned by the function `predict` is a "vector", which you can think of as a Python `array.array`, or numpy one-dimensional array.

"Joining" is not necessary, in the sense that the ordering of the elements in `pr` correspond to the rows in the table `withheld`. One only needs to add `pr` as an additional column to `withheld`
(see [Adding new column to existing DataFrame in Python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas)):

```py
withheld['predictions'] = pd.Series(pr,
                                    index=withheld.index)
```

By default this will add a column of integers (because R factors are encoded as integers). One can customize rpy2's conversion rather simply
(see http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.5/html/robjects_convert.html):

**note:** The version 2.6.0 of rpy2 will include the handling of pandas `Categorical` vectors, making the customization of the converter described below unnecessary.

```py
@robjects.conversion.ri2py.register(robjects.rinterface.SexpVector)
def ri2py_vector(vector):
    # based on
    # https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/src/a75413b09852991869332da615fa754923c32039/rpy/robjects/pandas2ri.py?at=default#cl-73

    # special case for factors
    if 'factor' in vector.rclass:
        res = pd.Categorical.from_codes(np.asarray(vector) - 1,
                                        categories = vector.do_slot('levels'),
                                        ordered = 'ordered' in vector.rclass)
    else:
        # use the numpy converter first
        res = numpy2ri.ri2py(obj)
    if isinstance(res, recarray):
        res = PandasDataFrame.from_records(res)
    return res
```

With this, the conversion of any rpy2 object into an non-rpy2 object will be returning a pandas `Categorical` whenever there is an R factor:

```py
robjects.conversion.ri2py(pr)
```

You may decide to add the result of this last conversion to your data table.

Note that the conversion to non-rpy2 objects has to be explicit (one is calling the converter). If you are using ipython, there is a way to make this implicit:
https://gist.github.com/lgautier/e2e8709776e0e0e93b8d
(and the originating thread https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issue/230/rmagic-specific-conversion).