# perform function using values from 2 columns and return result as new column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe called "final", it is indexed by date (as a datetimeindex), and each column named according to the following:

```
final = final[['stn', 'years_of_data', 'total_minutes', 'avg_daily', 'TOA_daily']]

final.head()

           stn  years_of_data   total_minutes   avg_daily   TOA_daily
date                    
1900-01-01  AlberniElementary   4       5760    26.100  101.700
1900-01-01  AlberniWeather      6       8265    25.000  101.700
1900-01-01  Arbutus             8       11162   31.200  101.700
1900-01-01  Arrowview           7       10080   23.200  101.700
1900-01-01  Bayside             6       8597    31.600  101.700
```

I would like to produce/add a column of values named "AC", based on a division of "avg_daily" and "TOA_daily".

I would like the result to look like:

```
           stn  years_of_data   total_minutes   avg_daily   TOA_daily   AC
date                    
1900-01-01  AlberniElementary   4       5760    26.100  101.700  0.257
1900-01-01  AlberniWeather      6       8265    25.000  101.700  0.246
1900-01-01  Arbutus             8       11162   31.200  101.700  0.307
1900-01-01  Arrowview           7       10080   23.200  101.700  0.228
1900-01-01  Bayside             6       8597    31.600  101.700  0.311
```

I have looked into ways of [creating a function to do this](http://manishamde.github.io/blog/2013/03/07/pandas-and-python-top-10/#create), but confused as to how to map and/or apply it in my case, especially the part returning the result [as a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas).

Comment: Have you tried `final["AC"] = final["avg_daily"] / final["TOA_daily"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
final['AC'] = final['avg_daily']/final['TOA_daily']
```

which adds the desired column.