# Dataframe Warning : SettingWithCopyWarning in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Processing file from 
http://portal.amfiindia.com/spages/NAV0.txt
to get output as follows:
31012017,1,1,135765,12,10.8536000,
31012017,1,1,135762,12,10.8543000,
31012017,1,1,135760,12,10.6599000,
31012017,1,1,135759,12,10.6554000,
31012017,1,1,135763,12,10.8536000,
..
..
..

I have tried using below code but getting below warning.

**CODE:**

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

#Sample file for NAV0.txt can be downloaded from url: http://portal.amfiindia.com/spages/NAV0.txt
#creating pandas with selected columns
df=pandas.read_table('NAV0.txt',sep=';',usecols=['Date','Scheme Code','Net Asset Value'])

#converting column with name 'Scheme Code' to digit to remove string part
fil_df=df[df['Scheme Code'].apply(lambda x : str(x).isdigit())]

#converting column with name 'Net Asset value' to numberic and set each value with 7 decimal places 
fil_df['Net Asset Value']=pandas.to_numeric(fil_df['Net Asset Value'],errors='coerce')
fil_df['Net Asset Value']=fil_df['Net Asset Value'].map(lambda x: '%2.7f' % x)


#Formating Date column as YYYMMDD
fil_df['Date']=pandas.to_datetime(fil_df['Date']).dt.strftime('%d%m%Y')

#adding extra column in dataframe
fil_df['ser1']=1
fil_df['ser2']=1
fil_df['period']=12
fil_df['lcol']=''
fil_df=fil_df[['Date','ser1','ser2','Scheme Code','period','Net Asset Value','lcol']]

#Converting datafile to csv
fil_df.to_csv('NAV_1.csv',index=False,header=None)
fil_df.dtypes
```

**ERROR:**

> c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\ipykernel__main__.py:12:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\ipykernel__main__.py:13:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\ipykernel__main__.py:17:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\ipykernel__main__.py:20:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\ipykernel__main__.py:21:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\ipykernel__main__.py:22:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\ipykernel__main__.py:23:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead

Csv file is getting generated as expected but how can I overcome this warning?
I have tried using 
`fil_df.loc[ pandas.to_numeric(fil_df['Net Asset Value'],errors='coerce').map(lambda x: '%2.7f' % x]`
but it didnt help.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need `copy` - `fil_df=df[df['Scheme Code'].apply(lambda x : str(x).isdigit())].copy()`

Comment: I am not getting warning at above line. warning coming from this line : `fil_df['Net Asset Value']=pandas.to_numeric(fil_df['Net Asset Value'],errors='coerce')`

Comment: Yes, but problem is in comment. If add copy, still problem?

Comment: Yes, I tried copy() still same problem

Comment: @jezrael Thanks! it works.. last time i placed it at another line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need add [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
fil_df=df[df['Scheme Code'].apply(lambda x : str(x).isdigit())].copy()
```

If you modify values in `fil_df` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`df`), and that Pandas does warning.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what your code is doing, you can use

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'
```

in your code to disable this warning.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get to the heart of the matter in adding new columns to a DataFrame from this guy's 2017 edit to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12555510/1330381). Basically the route is to use the `.assign('newCol' = enumerableValues )`