# Prevent duplication of rows when performing merge

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I've hit a wall with a data analysis project I'm working on.

Essentially, if I have example CSV 'A':

```
id   | item_num
A123 |     1
A123 |     2
B456 |     1
```

And I have example CSV 'B':

```
id   | description
A123 | Mary had a...
A123 | ...little lamb.
B456 | ...Its fleece...
```

If I perform a `merge` using `Pandas`, it ends up like this:

```
id   | item_num | description
A123 |     1    | Mary had a...
A123 |     2    | Mary had a...
A123 |     1    | ...little lamb.
A123 |     2    | ...little lamb.
B456 |     1    | Its fleece...
```

How could I instead make it become:

```
id   | item_num | description
A123 |     1    | Mary had a...
A123 |     2    | ...little lamb...
B456 |     1    | Its fleece...
```

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Import CSVs
first = pd.read_csv("../PATH_TO_CSV/A.csv")
print("Imported first CSV: " + str(first.shape))
second = pd.read_csv("../PATH_TO_CSV/B.csv")
print("Imported second CSV: " + str(second.shape))


# Create a resultant, but empty, DF, and then append the merge.
result = pd.DataFrame()
result = result.append(pd.merge(first, second), ignore_index = True)
print("Merged CSVs... resulting DataFrame is: " + str(result.shape))

# Lets do a "dedupe" to deal with an issue on how Pandas handles datetime merges
# I read about an issue where if datetime is involved, duplicate entires will be created.
result = result.drop_duplicates()
print("Deduping... resulting DataFrame is: " + str(result.shape))

# Save to another CSV
result.to_csv("EXPORT.csv", index=False)
print("Saved to file.")
```

I would really appreciate any help - I'm very stuck! And I'm dealing with 20,000+ rows.

Thanks.

Edit: my post was marked as a potential duplicate. It's not, as I'm not necessarily trying to add a column - I'm just trying to prevent the `description` to be multiplied by the number of `item_num` that are attributed to a particular `id`.

---

**UPDATE, 6/21:**

How could I do the merge, if the 2 DFs looked like this instead?

```
id   | item_num | other_col
A123 |     1    | lorem ipsum
A123 |     2    | dolor sit
A123 |     3    | amet, consectetur
B456 |     1    | lorem ipsum
```

And I have example CSV 'B':

```
id   | item_num | description
A123 |     1    | Mary had a...
A123 |     2    | ...little lamb.
B456 |     1    | ...Its fleece...
```

So I end up with:

```
id   | item_num |  other_col  | description
A123 |     1    | lorem ipsum | Mary Had a...
A123 |     2    | dolor sit   | ...little lamb.
B456 |     1    | lorem ipsum | ...Its fleece...
```

Meaning, the row that has the 3, with "amet, consectetur" in the "other_col" is ignored.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding new column to existing DataFrame in Python pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas)

Comment: It looks like you want to [`concat` or `append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html), not `merge`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
In [135]: result = A.merge(B.assign(item_num=B.groupby('id').cumcount()+1))

In [136]: result
Out[136]:
     id  item_num       description
0  A123         1     Mary had a...
1  A123         2   ...little lamb.
2  B456         1  ...Its fleece...
```

Explanation: we can create "virtual" `item_num` column in the `B` DF for joining:

```
In [137]: B.assign(item_num=B.groupby('id').cumcount()+1)
Out[137]:
     id       description  item_num
0  A123     Mary had a...         1
1  A123   ...little lamb.         2
2  B456  ...Its fleece...         1
```

Comment: I wish this had worked for me, but it seems to have just not included any of the data from one of the CSVs. In fact, the resulting CSV is just a copy of one of the CSVs.

Comment: @kabaname, are you sure you have assigned the result of merging back?

Comment: nevermind, so I got it to produce the result - but it's still multiplying the rows so as to repeat the descriptions for `1` and `2` just like in my example. In other words, `Mary had a...` is repeating for both 1 and 2 and then `...little lamb.` is also repeating, still. @maxu

Comment: Just thought I'd circle back and let you know this works fine! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @MaxU, I have an update to this problem and was wondering if you could shed some insight?

Answer (score 1):

try indexing your df and then drop duplicates:

```
df = df.set_index(['id', 'item_num']).drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: So I tried that, and it seems to have removed both columns and all data... but that did solve the issue of duplication as the remaining data was not duplicated like before.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need concat

```
result = pd.concat([df1.set_index('id'), df2.set_index('id')],axis = 1).reset_index()
```

You get

```
    id      item_no     description
0   A123    1           Mary had a...
1   A123    2           ...little lamb
2   B456    1           ...Its fleece...
```

Comment: I'm getting a `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (13, 10799), indices imply (13, 6240)`