# Pandas merge two datasets with same number of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables with same number of rows (second table is computed from first one by processing of text inside T1). I have both of them stored as pandas dataframe. T2 is no common column with T1. This is example because my tables are huge:

```
T1:
| name  | street  | city   |
|-------|---------|--------|
| David | street1 | Prague |
| John  | street2 | Berlin |
| Joe   | street3 | London |

T2:
| computed1 | computed2 |
|-----------|-----------|
| 0.5       | 0.3       |
| 0.2       | 0.8       |
| 0.1       | 0.6       |

Merged:
| name  | street  | city   | computed1 | computed2 |
|-------|---------|--------|-----------|-----------|
| David | street1 | Prague | 0.5       | 0.3       |
| John  | street2 | Berlin | 0.2       | 0.8       |
| Joe   | street3 | London | 0.1       | 0.6       |
```

I tried these commands:

```
pd.concat([T1,T2])
pd.merge([T1,T2])
result=T1.join(T1)
```

With concat and merge I will get only first thousand combined and rest is filled with nan (I double checked that both are same size), and with .join it not combine them because there is nothing in common.

Is there any way how to combine these two tables in pandas?

Thanks

Comment: maybe this SO question can help you? : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas)

Comment: There is same size of both `DataFrames`? Maybe need `pd.concat([T1,T2], axis=1)` I guess

Comment: Or if different indices but same length of both DataFrames need `pd.concat([T1.reset_index(drop=True),T2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)`

Comment: thank you guys, @jezrael solution with reset index seems to works! Thanks all!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need `reset_index()` before `concat` for default indices:

```
df = pd.concat([T1.reset_index(drop=True),T2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

Comment: Note for those that copy and paste lines of code and may not have invisible unicode viewing enabled, VS Code identified two hidden unicode chars `U+200c` and `U+200b` within the `u` and `e` of the last `drop=True`, which has to be removed before code can be run.

Comment: @Alice - thank you, code was changed.

Answer (score 7):

I want to add that pd.concat can do what you want by just providing the axis as columns. like this:

```
pd.concat([T1,T2],axis=1)
```

Comment: Check [jezrael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47657006/5699807) in case you are using default indices! using this answer may give you unexpected NaNs!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the names of my dataframes that I want to merge is

```
X_Numerical #shape = (4055, 5) #This dataframe has no NaN rows
X_Categorical #shape = (4055, 13) #This dataframe has no NaN rows
```

I think the following methods could work but it has a downside:

```
X_features_main  = pd.concat([X_Categorical, X_Numerical.reindex(X_Categorical.index)], axis=1) #shape = (4055, 18) & will have NaN vaules
```

Downside:

1. You will end up with various NAN values as showing in the Pandas documentations at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html

The following method overcome that downside.

1. Adding a new column called index for each of the DataFrames

```py
X_Categorical['index'] = range(1, len(X_Categorical) + 1)
X_Numerical['index'] = range(1, len(X_Numerical) + 1)
```

2. Merging the two DataFrames based on that common column

```py
X_features_main = X_Categorical.merge(X_Numerical, on = 'index', how = 'left')
```

3. Dropping the column the merging was done at

```py
X_features_main = X_features_main.drop(['index'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to merge on the index values:

```
df = T1.reset_index().merge(T2.reset_index(), left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left)
```