# When joined two Data Frames of same shape (480,6) with different columns, it created shape (175000,12)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

> I couldn't put the entire data frame as it looks clumsy, so I added
>   data types.

```
DF1 Columns:

    Dependents            object
    ApplicantIncome        int64
    CoapplicantIncome    float64
    LoanAmount           float64
    Loan_Amount_Term     float64
    Credit_History       float64

DF2 Columns:

    Gender            int64
    Married           int64
    Education         int64
    Self_Employed     int64
    Credit_History    int64
    Property_Area     int64
```

> My intention is to put two data frames side by side and make it a
>   single data frame shape(480,12) but I'm getting more rows with
>   repeated data entire column.

Comment: it would help if you could prepare a [mcve] . Please show us the code, you don't need to use your original dataframes, you can always make *example* dataframes to demonstrate the same effects.

Comment: how did you join them ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two dataframes side-by-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891575/how-to-merge-two-dataframes-side-by-side)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas merge two datasets with same number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47655296/pandas-merge-two-datasets-with-same-number-of-rows)

Comment: Is Credit_History Column in both dataframe is diifferent?

Comment: @souravkhanna Credit_History is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for something like `DF1.join(DF2)`, but you should prepare an example of your inputs and the output you want. Also, you could use `pd.concat([DF1, DF2], axis=1)`.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

You need pandas `concat` and passing `axis=1` which will make dataframes be joined side by side (vertically instead of horizontally). The code should be as follows:

`final_df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1)`