# How to add values to a new column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new named column in a Pandas dataframe, insert first value into it, and then add another values to the same column:

Something like:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame()
df['New column'].append('a')
df['New column'].append('b')
df['New column'].append('c')

etc.
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dont do it, [because it's slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871316/2901002):

> 6. **updating an empty frame a-single-row-at-a-time**. I have seen this method used WAY too much. It is by far the slowest. It is probably common place (and reasonably fast for some python structures), but a DataFrame does a fair number of checks on indexing, so this will always be very slow to update a row at a time. Much better to create new structures and concat.

Better to create a list of data and create `DataFrame` by contructor:

```
vals = ['a','b','c']

df = pandas.DataFrame({'New column':vals})
```

Answer (score 9):

If I understand, correctly you want to append a value to an existing column in a pandas data frame. The thing is with DFs you need to maintain a matrix-like shape so the number of rows is equal for each column what you can do is add a column with a default value and then update this value with

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     df.at[index, 'new_column'] = new_value
```

Comment: I've hit a similar problem. What doesn't this work:  row['new_column']=new_value?

Answer (score 0):

If in case you need to add random values to the newly created column, you could also use

```
df['new_column']= np.random.randint(1, 9, len(df))
```