# Pandas - Adding a column to DF href

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on a webscrape script. The pandas data frame that is generated is fantastic however I need to add a unique_id column with the value of a href URL contained in the HTML.

```
<td><a href="/admin/tasks/edit/82689"> ADDRESS </a> CLIENT </td>
```

Currently the Pandas data frame has a column containing 'ADDRESS CLIENT' but how can I add a seperate column containing the href URL?

I am currently able to get a comma separated list of the unique_id values using the following:

```
unique_id = [a['href'] for a in table.select('a[href]')]
```

any direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: You mena `pd['url']=unique_id`?

Comment: Here is the a unique question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do it will be using the pandas.DataFrame.assign method

```
df.assign(url=unique_id)
```

This will give you a new column in the DataFrame with name url and values the values from the numpy array. As far as I know column assignment like `df['url] = unique_id` is deprecated. You can read more
[here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html).