# Efficient way to add new column to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I know two ways of adding a new column to pandas dataframe

```
df_new = df.assign(new_column=default_value)
```

and

```
df[new_column] = default_value
```

The first one does not add columns inplace, but the second one does. So, which one is more efficient to use?

Apart from these two is there is any all the more efficient method than these?

Comment: I think question is about performance, so reopened.

Comment: The original question discusses relative performance in the comments. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas/35387129

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think second one, [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) is used if want nice code witch chaining all functions - one line code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.rand(10000)})

default_value = 10

In [114]: %timeit df_new = df.assign(new_column=default_value)
228 µs ± 4.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [115]: %timeit df['new_column'] = default_value
86.1 µs ± 654 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

I use perfplot for ploting:

[image: pic]

---

```
import perfplot

default_value = 10

def chained(df):
    df = df.assign(new_column=default_value)
    return df

def no_chained(df):
    df['new_column'] = default_value
    return df

def make_df(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.rand(n)})
    return df

perfplot.show(
    setup=make_df,
    kernels=[chained, no_chained],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(2, 25)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=False,
    xlabel='len(df)')
```