# Add new columns to pivoted dataframe data

Tags: pandas

I've wrangled my raw data into the following pivot, now I need to insert 2 new columns which represents difference for "avg" and "vol" values 2016 over 2014 but am stuck. New to coding,

thx!

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); you'll get more help if you provide some code for others to use to get started.

Comment: Also, is that pandas or Excel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding new column to existing DataFrame in Python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas)