# How to add column to a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
db_fields = ("id", "email", "status", "source")
df = DataFrame(results)
for col in db_fields:
    if col not in df.columns:
          COLUMN IS MISSING - COMMAND TO ADD COLUMN
```

If for example `status` column is missing it needs to be added to the data frame with nothing as value so when I export the `df` to `csv` I will always have the same schema of fields.

I know that to remove column I should do:

```
df = df.drop(col, 1)
```

But I don't know what is the best way to add column with empty value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding new column to existing DataFrame in Python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create array of non exist columns and create new one with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a1','a2', 'b1'],
                  'a': ['a1','a2', 'b1'],
                  'source': ['a1','a2', 'b1']})
print (df)
   id   a source
0  a1  a1     a1
1  a2  a2     a2
2  b1  b1     b1

db_fields = ("id", "email", "status", "source")

#get missing columns
diff = np.setdiff1d(np.array(db_fields), df.columns)
print (diff)
['email' 'status']

#get original columns not existed in db_fields
diff1 = np.setdiff1d(df.columns, np.array(db_fields)).tolist()
print (diff1)
['a']

#add missing columns with change order
d = dict.fromkeys(diff, np.nan)
df = df.assign(**d)[diff1 + list(db_fields)]
print (df)
    a  id  email  status source
0  a1  a1    NaN     NaN     a1
1  a2  a2    NaN     NaN     a2
2  b1  b1    NaN     NaN     b1
```

---

```
#if necessary first db_fields
df = df.assign(**d)[list(db_fields) + diff1]
print (df)
   id  email  status source   a
0  a1    NaN     NaN     a1  a1
1  a2    NaN     NaN     a2  a2
2  b1    NaN     NaN     b1  b1
```

Comment: Since I'm doing this in loop for 5 diffrent dataframes. How can I make sure that columns will be in same order? If something was added it adds in the end.. so I can get two dataframe with same columns but in diffrent order.

Comment: @Luis - How working `df.assign(**d).sort_index(axis=1)` ?

Comment: @Luis - Solution was modify - all columns defined in `db_fields` are in the end of data or in first positions

Comment: I did df.reindex(db_fields) but I guess yours method works too.

Comment: @Luis - yes, if want only columns from `db_fields` then `df = df.assign(**d)[list(db_fields)]` is another solution or `df.reindex(db_fields, axis=1) `

Answer (score 1):

This method will added status column with Null values:

```
import numpy as np
df['status'] = np.nan
```

Alternatively:

```
df['status'] = None
```

So:

```
db_fields = ("id", "email", "status", "source")
for col in db_fields:
    if col not in df.columns:
        df[col] = None
```

Comment: Would df[col] = np.nan  work? and why do I need numpy for the none value?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have it, plain and simple, in just **one line**:

```
import numpy as np
db_fields = ("id", "email", "status", "source")
df = DataFrame(results)
for col in db_fields:
    if col not in df.columns:
        # Add the column
        df[col] = np.nan
```

**BTW:** You can also drop a column using `df.drop(inplace=True)`.