# adding lists to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
A   B   C
1  NaN NaN 
2  NaN NaN
3  NaN NaN
4  NaN NaN
```

I want this:

```
A   B         C
1  'Blue'   'Purple'
2  'Yellow' 'Yellow'   
3  'Green'  'Orange'  
4  'Blue'   'Brown'
```

What I have tried to do:

df1.B = ['Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue']
df1.C = ['Purple', 'Yellow', 'Orange', 'Brown']

But i get the following error:
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

But there are the same number of colors in the list as in the df.

Please help.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using - I cannot repeat your issue.

Comment: What do you see for `len(df.index)` or `df.shape[0]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A column in a dataframe is a `Series` object so you want

```
 df['B'] = pd.Series( ['Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue'])
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try use:

```
df1 = df1.assign(B=pd.Series(['Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue']).values)
```

And there is more information about on this post:
[Adding new column to existing DataFrame in Python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

Well if the length of the list that you want to assign to column B and C are equal to number of rows in dataframe then you can directly assign the list as below :

```
df['B'] = ['Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue']
```