# How to shift a cell depending on a value in another column in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
id | time
1  | 10:21
1  | 10:22
1  | 10:23
2  | 10:40
2  | 10:45
2  | 10:50
```

I would like to add a new column as follows:

```
id | time  | new_time
1  | 10:21 | 10:22
1  | 10:22 | 10:23
1  | 10:23 | None
2  | 10:40 | 10:45
2  | 10:45 | 10:50
2  | 10:50 | None
```

That means, I would like to create the new column by matching the values in the `id` column. For example, if the `id` values for two consecutive rows are the same then I would like to add the value in the `new_time` (in the first column) from the `time` value of the second column. If the `id` values are not the same then I would like to add `None` for the `new_time` value.How can I achieve this using python or pandas?

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind this?

Comment: I think someone has already asked it. Lemme check!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding new column to existing DataFrame in Python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas)

Comment: I am sorry for not explaining it clearly. I would like to create the new column by matching the values in the `id` column. For example, if the `id` values for two consecutive rows are the same then I would like to add the value in the `new_time` (in the first column) from the `time` value of the second column. If the `id` values are not the same then I would like to add `None` for the `new_time` value.

Comment: @RafaelBarros: I am not sure if your provided link resolves my issue. I would like to use (by shifting and matching) the existing columns to calculate  the new column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use .shift() to get next record:

```
df['new_time'] = df.shift(-1).time
```

Results:

```
    id  time    new_time
0   1   10:21   10:22
1   1   10:22   10:23
2   1   10:23   10:40
3   2   10:40   10:45
4   2   10:45   10:50
5   2   10:50   NaN
```

Then assign `np.NaN` to the last row for each id

```
df.loc[df.groupby('id', as_index= False).nth([-1]).index, 'new_time'] = np.NaN
```

Results:

```
id  time    new_time
0   1   10:21   10:22
1   1   10:22   10:23
2   1   10:23   NaN
3   2   10:40   10:45
4   2   10:45   10:50
5   2   10:50   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It was helpful. I solved my issue in the following way:

`df['new_time'] = df.groupby(['id'])['time'].shift(-1)`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming ID is currently the index, I would try:

```py
df = df.reset_index()
shifted = df.shift(-1)
df['new_time'] = shifted.time
df.loc[df.id != shifted.id, "new_time"] = None
df = df.set_index("id")
```

If it's not an index you can just skip the `reset_index` and `set_index` lines.

It basically shifts the entire dataframe, matches them up together and wherever IDs are no longer the same it sets those values to None.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It was helpful. I solved my issue in the following way:

`df['new_time'] = df.groupby(['id'])['time'].shift(-1)`

Comment: I did not know that pandas let you shift on a group... That is good to know