# How can I add a column to an existing filled dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I tried to add value to a new column for an existing data frame:

```
val_df["perplexity"][10]=14
```

There is no column named `perplexity` and I thought this will create the column. I guessed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13843741/2651073) says the same, but I got the following error:

```
KeyError: 'perplexity'
```

Comment: So if you want to add new column called perplexity, you need to specify the values. What are those values?

Comment: @DanielMesejo they must be set in a loop, however I can set a default value of `0`

Comment: Then I guess you are just find doing `val_df["perplexity"] = 0` and then setting the other values with the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 'perplexity' column does not exist yet, a specific index (row) cannot be accessed. So, create the column and assign a default value, then update specific row's value.

```
val_df["perplexity"] = ''
val_df["perplexity"][10] = 14
```

**EDIT:** As suggested by @ALollz below, chained indexing should be avoided to avoid the SettingWithCopy warning. The following code is recommended.

```
val_df.loc[10, 'perplexity'] = 14
```

Comment: chained assignment should be avoided. Use `.loc`: `val_df.loc[10, 'perplexity'] = 14`

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing it out. I have added this as an edit.