# How to add columns in the data when columns are not present?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My data doesn't contain columns when I am adding the columns in the data using `dataFrame.columns = ['XYZ','ABC']` then the 1st row is getting replaced by the column names.

Comment: This is just renaming the columns. (What you call the 1st row are column headers.)

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is pretty much explained here - [Adding new column to existing DataFrame in Python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas)
.
To keep it short: `df['new_column'] = None # or any other value`.