# What Python data structures allow for easy access to values with multiple indices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I work in Freight shipping, and I recently built a scraper that scraped market rates of shipments based on 3 features: origin city, destination city, and time period.

Currently, I have these results stored in a csv/xlsx file that has this data outlined as follows:

[image: Sample Data]

My current project involves comparing what we actually paid for shipments versus the going market rate. From my scraped data, I need a way to rapidly access the:

**AVERAGE MARKET RATE**

based on: **MONTH**, **ORIGIN CITY**, and **DESTINATION CITY**.

Since I know what *we* paid for shipping on a particular day, if I can access the average market rate from that month, I can perform a simple subtraction to tell us how much we over or underpaid.

I am relatively proficient with using Pandas dataframes, and my first instincts were to try to combine a dataframe with a dictionary to call values based on those features, but I am unsure of how I can do that exactly.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.  Make it easy for us to copy and paste into our editors for testing.  
[You should not post code as an image because:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas, you could [add your data as a new column in your csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas). Then you could just subtract the two indexes, eg `df['mean'] - df['paid']`

You could do that in Excel too.

As a side note, you'll probably want to update your csv so that each row has the appropriate city - maybe it's harder to read, but it'll definitely be easier to work with in your code.