# Using sumproduct or dot function in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following 2 tables, df and name_df, where the number of people is not limited to 2 and can increase. Under the name columns (ie. John and Mary), a 1 represents he/she consumed the item while 0 represents did not consume:

```
df
item   price John  Mary
apple  2     1     1
mango  5     0     1

name_df
name
John
Mary
```

I want to calculate the sumproduct of each person and join the column to the name_df column. I want the result to look like this:

```
name_df
name   sumproduct
John   2
Mary   7
```

My main problem is to find out how to calculate sumproduct using python/pandas. I know a `.dot()` function will get the result I want but how can I append those results to each respective person?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding new column to existing DataFrame in Python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can melt using the `name_df` to determine `id_vars`, and `groupby`.

---

```
u = df.melt(df.columns ^ name_df['name'])

u.price.mul(u.value).groupby(u.variable).sum()
```

```
variable
John    2
Mary    7
dtype: int64
```