# Adding column to a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, data-manipulation, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to add a column to a dataframe

In `yf_test.csv` I have two columns:

[image: original data]

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

ticker = pd.read_csv('yf_test.csv')
filtered = ticker['Filter1']
alist = []
for x in filtered:
    y = yf.Ticker(x)
    z = y.history(start=str(pnldate),end=str(pnldate))
    alist.append(z)

yf_data = pd.concat(alist)
price = yf_data['Close']
ticker['price']=price
```

What I wanted to do is to pull the prices from Yahoo Finance and then have them populate in a new column on dataframe `ticker`.

But when I do the above, I get an error:

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you just need to use a different name than "price" for the column - try "stock_price" or something like that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas/35387129#35387129