# Adding column of values to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm doing a simple sentiment analysis and am stuck on something that I feel is very simple. I'm trying to add an new column with a set of values, in this example `compound` values. But after the for loop iterates it adds the same value for all the rows rather than a value for each iteration. The `compound` values are the last column in the DataFrame. There should be a quick fix. thanks!

```
for i, row in real.iterrows():
   real['compound'] = sid.polarity_scores(real['title'][i])['compound']


title   text    subject date                                                        compound
0   As U.S. budget fight looms, Republicans flip t...   WASHINGTON (Reuters) - The head of a conservat...   politicsNews    December 31, 2017   0.2263
1   U.S. military to accept transgender recruits o...   WASHINGTON (Reuters) - Transgender people will...   politicsNews    December 29, 2017   0.2263
2   Senior U.S. Republican senator: 'Let Mr. Muell...   WASHINGTON (Reuters) - The special counsel inv...   politicsNews    December 31, 2017   0.2263
3   FBI Russia probe helped by Australian diplomat...   WASHINGTON (Reuters) - Trump campaign adviser ...   politicsNews    December 30, 2017   0.2263
4   Trump wants Postal Service to charge 'much mor...   SEATTLE/WASHINGTON (Reuters) - President Donal...   politicsNews    December 29, 2017   0.2263
```

[image]

Comment: `real['compound'] =` assigns the whole column. Did you mean `row['compound']`?

Comment: It didn't work for me when I switched to `row['compound']`. I would like to add to a row after every iteration. My initial though was `.append`

Comment: That loop is not very idiomatic, have you read the Pandas docs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding new column to existing DataFrame in Python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
real['compound'] = real.apply(lambda row: sid.polarity_scores(row['title'])['compound'], axis=1)
```