# TypeError: 'DataFrame' object cannot be interpreted as an integer in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have a simple question, I am creating new column in a list of dataFrame within function. I got this error

```
data['datenum'] = np.zeros((data))

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas

Answer (score 1):

Your argument to np.zeros needs to be an integer. Right now you have data, which you say is a DataFrame. Perhaps you're looking for:

```
data['datenum'] = np.zeros(data.shape[0])
```

If you have multiple dataframes, you can do the following:

```
for data in dataframes: 
    data['datenum'] = np.zeros(data.shape[0])
```

Comment: thanks @ananyajoshi I actually have list of dataframes not only single dataframe

Comment: Hi @lffi not sure what you mean, if you need any more help do let me know with more details!

Comment: @anayajoshi  I actually have list of DataFrames e.g df = [df1,df2,df3....]  which I am using in function so I need to create zero column for each dataframe in the list

Comment: The above should work now, just replace dataframes with df. Please accept the answer if so.