# How to make a column of set of lists in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dataframe

I have a data frame in hand, now i want to add one more column in that data frame. that column will be a set of lists, ie, if the length of the data frame is 10, the column will be set of 10 lists. Each row associate with one list. How can i make this? And initially those lists will be blank list so that i can append objects further.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding new column to existing DataFrame in Python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

I can answer your question with this code(length of df is 3 and not 10)

```
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.DataFrame([{'Name': 'Chris', 'Item Purchased': 'Sponge', 'Cost': 22.50},
               {'Name': 'ABC', 'Item Purchased': 'Chocolate', 'Cost': 2.50},
               {'Name': 'Filip', 'Item Purchased': 'Spoon', 'Cost': 5.00}],
              index=['Store 1', 'Store 1', 'Store 2'])
    df
    df['Date'] = [['December 1','December 10'], ['January 1','February 5'], ['mid- 
    May','mid-September']]
    df
```

The image shows the output
[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

A new column in a `pandas Dataframe` can be added as simple as :

```
df['new_column_name'] = your_list
```

If `your_list` is nested, you can append new values into its elements, by the usual `append` function (for example, into `your_list[0]` by `df['new_column_name'][0].append(value)`)

Answer (score 0):

I can give the answer of my question i think.
Suppose i have a dataset called XYZ, It has @ column A,B. Now i want to add one more column C which is a set of lists ie, there are same number of lists as number of rows.
`XYZ = pd.read_csv('untitled.csv', usecols = ['A', 'B']) XYZ['C'] = pd.Series([]*len(XYZ), dtype = object) for i in range(len(XYZ)): XYZ['C'][i] = []`