# Is there a faster way to fill in a new column in a dataframe based on exsiting ones than using loc in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, pandas-loc

I have a dataframe that includes the total number of products made in a factory for every day but it is a cumulative field and not daily values. I am trying to calculate daily values by just subtracting every day's cumulative number from next day's number. Here is the code I'm using. I am using `loc` to make sure that it inserts the new values in the original dataframe. This way it takes 10 seconds for 1000 rows which is kind of long, since the original data is much larger. Wondering if there is a faster way.

before:

```
    date        sum     
0   2020-03-24  10  
1   2020-03-25  50  
2   2020-03-26  90  
3   2020-03-27  140 
4   2020-03-28  180
```

code:

```
for i in range(1, 1000):
    data.loc[i, 'daily_products'] = data.loc[i, 'sum'] - data.loc[i-1, 'sum']
```

after:

```
    date        sum     daily_products
0   2020-03-24  10  
1   2020-03-25  50      40
2   2020-03-26  90      40
3   2020-03-27  140     50
4   2020-03-28  180     40
```

and the time it takes for 1000 rows:

```
Total runtime of the program is 9.468996286392212
```

Comment: What about `data['daily_products'] = data['sum'] - data['sum'].shift(-1) ` ?

Comment: Or just `data["sum"].diff()`?

Answer (score 3):

Let use

`data['daily_products'] = data['sum'].diff()`

> 159 µs ± 3.66 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops
> each)

versus

```
for i in range(1, len(data)-1):
    data.loc[i, 'daily_products'] = data.loc[i, 'sum'] - data.loc[i-1, 'sum']
```

> 716 µs ± 26.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops
> each)

and...

```
data['daily_products'] = data['sum'] - data['sum'].shift(-1)
```

> 305 µs ± 6.18 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops
> each)

Comment: The comparison would have been even better with `.diff(-1)` actually. Some "frictions" may occur when not defaulting.

Comment: .diff(-1) provides a negative number not correct in my opinion. However, it doesn't affect the times much at all.  Mabye 10 microseconds.

Comment: Thanks guys. very helpful

Answer (score 1):

To address your question specifically, something you can do is using [`.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

```
data['daily_products'] = data['sum'] - data['sum'].shift(-1)
```

Or cf @Scott's answer, in your case with [`.diff(-1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)

---

Note that [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) is a method of [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), which means that this is somehow a reserved name you should not use. Indeed, using such name for your variable prevents you from getting it by doing `data.sum`. By opposition, you can do `data.daily_products` since this column name does not enter in conflict with pandas's name space. [*Once it has been defined* though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas).