# Pandas: How to calculate the percentage of one column against another?

Tags: python, pandas, math, percentage

I am just trying to calculate the percentage of one column against another's total, but I am unsure how to do this in Pandas so the calculation gets added into a new column.

Let's say, for argument's sake, my data frame has two attributes:

- Number of Green Marbles
- Total Number of Marbles

Now, how would I calculate the **percentage** of the **Number of Green Marbles** out of the **Total Number of Marbles in Pandas**?

Obviously, I know that the calculation will be something like this:

- (Number of Green Marbles / Total Number of Marbles) * 100

Thanks - any help is much appreciated!

Comment: show your data and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, arithmetic operations on pandas dataframes are element-wise, so this is as simple as it can be:

```py
import pandas as pd

>>> d = pd.DataFrame()
>>> d['green'] = [3,5,10,12]
>>> d['total'] = [8,8,20,20]
>>> d
   green  total
0      3      8
1      5      8
2     10     20
3     12     20
>>> d['percent_green'] = d['green'] / d['total'] * 100
>>> d
   green  total  percent_green
0      3      8           37.5
1      5      8           62.5
2     10     20           50.0
3     12     20           60.0
```

**References:**

- [`pandas.DataFrame.div` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html);
- [Adding new column to existing dataframe in python pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas)

Comment: Thank you very much - that is simpler than I thought. I did have something like that in mind, but I was unsure. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

df['percentage columns'] = (df['Number of Green Marbles']) / (df['Total Number of Marbles'] ) * 100

Answer (score 0):

Here is my comparison of regular vs vectorized approach:

```
%timeit us_consum['Commercial_%ofUS'] = us_consum['Commercial_MWhrs']*100/us_consum['Total US consumption (MWhr)']

351 µs ± 22.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)


%timeit us_consum['Commercial_%ofUS'] = (us_consum['Commercial_MWhrs'].div(us_consum['Total US consumption (MWhr)']))*100 
337 µs ± 60.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```