# How can an array be added as a separate column to a CSV file using numpy (preferable) or python 3 without overwriting the CSV file or data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, csv

The new data to be appended has a shorter length!

Here is an example:

```
Add numpy array:
ema  =  [3.3  3.4  3.5  3.6]

                                            (csv now has 3-columns of equal length)
1.1  2.1    append  ema  to end up with:    1.1  2.1  0
1.2  2.2                                    1.2  2.2  0
1.3  2.3                                    1.3  2.3  3.3
1.4  2.4                                    1.4  2.4  3.4
1.5  2.5                                    1.5  2.5  3.5
1.6  2.6                                    1.6  2.6  3.6
```

Comment: Best way would be to read the old data as a `pandas` dataframe and then append the column to it and fill empty columns with 0s and finally writing it back to csv.

Comment: A `csv` file is a text file.  You can add new lines (rows) to such a file, but you can't add columns without writing a whole new file.  Imagine adding material to written text.  Unless text has space on to the right of each line, you can only add stuff the bottom (or a new page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kinshukdua's comment suggestion as code:

> Best way would be to read the old data as a pandas dataframe and then
> append the column to it and fill empty columns with 0s and finally
> writing it back to csv.

using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12555510/913098)

```
import pandas as pd
my_csv_path = r"path/to/csv.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(my_csv_path)
ema_padded = np.concatenate([np.zeros(len(df) - ema.shape[0]), ema])
df['ema'] = pd.Series(ema_padded, index=df.index)
df.to_csv(my_csv_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

df.to_csv(file_path, index=False)

Comment: that doesn't handle shorter data than csv cols