# Python Dataframe add a value to new column based on value from another column

Tags: python, dataframe

What is the shortest way to achieve this scenario::

Dataframe1: (Dataframe1 Column A has additional Values because of which i can not simply perform  df2["Column C"] = df["Column B"] )

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Valu 2 |
| Cell w | Valu 8 |
| Cell 3 | Valu 4 |

Condition: Insert Value at Column C (New column) of Dataframe2 from Column B of Dataframe1 where Column A's value from Dataframe1 'Cell 1' matches Column X's value from Dataframe2 'Cell 1'

Dataframe2 Initial: (Has only Column X & Column J)

| Column X | Column J |
| --- | --- |
| cell 1 | Data c |
| cell 3 | Data f |

Dataframe2 Final: (Which had only Column X & Column J, now has Column C with above mentioned condition)

| Column X | Column J | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Data c | Valu 2 |
| Cell 3 | Data f | Valu 4 |

```
for key, value3 in df['Column A'].iteritems():
        value2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(value3, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        value2 = str(value2)
        for key2, value4 in df2['Column X'].iteritems():
            sep = ' '
            value = str(value4)
            stripped = value.split(sep, 1)[0]
            if value2 == stripped:
                x = df[df['Column A']==value3]['Column B'].values[0]
                df2['Column C'][key2] = x
```

Comment: Why not add a column to df2 with `df2["Column C"] = df["Column B"]` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/how-to-add-a-new-column-to-an-existing-dataframe

Comment: I cant add column B directly because Dataframe1 has additional Column A values which are not Present in Column X in Dataframe2

Comment: Then I'm not sure this is the fastest way, but you could look into joining the two dataframes and removing the rows with NaN values (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do it with `DataFrame.join(...)` operation. You can indeed also use the `DataFrame.merge(...)` method as well.

```py
import pandas as pd

# definition of the dataframes
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B"])
df.A = [1, 2, 3]
df.B = ["b1", "b2", "b3"]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["X"])
df2.X = [1, 3]

# join operation
df2_final = df2.set_index("X").join(df.set_index("A")).reset_index()
```

Which outputs:

```py
   X   B
0  1  b1
1  3  b3
```

Comment: This is brilliant, i can conditionalize the operation without extra effort at the end, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `merge` to achieve the result that you want.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col A':['Cell 1','Cell 3'],'Col B':['Cell 2','Cell 4']})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col X':['Cell 1','Cell 3'],'Col Y':['Cell c','Cell F']})
df2 = df1.merge(df,left_on='Col X',right_on='Col A',how='inner') 
df2
```

After this you can manipulate the data(remove extra columns, rename columns) but this would help you get 'Col B' into df1 if df['Col A'] = df1['Col X]

Comment: This was really simple, but @SpaceBurger's answer addresses the exact issue i am facing, but thank you for your idea, i will keep that in mind :)