# How to remark duplicate records in Excel?

Tags: python, excel

1. I have the excel file.

   ```
   'Born Date   Student Name  Duplicate 
    2001-01-01     Tommy
    2001-03-04     Annie         
    2001-05-13     Billy
    2001-07-31     Bob
    2001-03-04     Annie         
    2001-04-04     Janet
    2001-11-05     Betty
    2001-12-15     Lucy          
    2001-08-25     Nicky
    2001-12-15     Lucy          
    2001-07-31     John
   ```
2. I want to use Python update the excel file like as below result

   ```
   Born Date   Student Name  Duplicate 
    2001-01-01     Tommy
    2001-03-04     Annie        Yes
    2001-05-13     Billy
    2001-07-31     Bob
    2001-03-04     Annie        Yes
    2001-04-04     Janet
    2001-11-05     Betty
    2001-12-15     Lucy         Yes
    2001-08-25     Nicky
    2001-12-15     Lucy         Yes
    2001-07-31     John
   ```
3. Below is my code... I'm a beginner in Python please teach me how to coding, Thanks!

   ```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Desktop/Studen List.xlsx')
    dc = df.duplicated()
    print(dc)
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is not too far from answering your problem. All you need is to assign the pandas serie returned to a new column in your dataframe ([How to add a new column to an existing DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/how-to-add-a-new-column-to-an-existing-dataframe)). I would complete it as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Desktop/Studen List.xlsx') #ideally you would prefere using relative paths (i.e. ./relative_path_to_file/Student_list.xlsx) 
df['Duplicate'] = df.duplicated()
df['Duplicate'] = df['Duplicate'].replace({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'}) # eventually if you want Yes / No labels rather than True / False

df.to_excel('./relative_path/Modified_Student_list.xlsx')
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to understand a bit further:

```
import pandas as pd


def insert_boolean_for_duplicates(excelfile):
  df = pd.read_excel(excelfile)
  dc = df.duplicated()
  print(dc)
  print('------------')
  print(df)
  print('------------')
  print(dc.drop_duplicates())
  print('------------')
  print(dc.values)
.
if __name__ == '__main__':
  insert_boolean_for_duplicates('StudentList.xlsx')
```

I recommend you to check out [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html), It may help you out.