# How can I add a column with numbered 4 rows by 4 rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to add a column, that do what's here in the example.

example:

```
data
1
2
4
6
8
9
7
5
3
2
```

and I need a column like this one

```
data  new_col
1 1
2 1
4 1
6 1
8 2
9 2
7 2
5 2
3 3
2 3
...
```

and so on.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the logic? +1 every 4 numbers?

Comment: `df['new_col'] = np.arange(len(df))//4+1` or similar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a new column to an existing DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/how-to-add-a-new-column-to-an-existing-dataframe)