# Add columns to existing dataframe with a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I try to build a dataframe with the first columns of several other dataframes with a loop. All of them have same index.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(3, 2)), columns=list('AB'), index=('class1', 'class2', 'class3'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(3, 2)), columns=list('CD'), index=('class1', 'class2', 'class3')) 
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(3, 2)), columns=list('EF'), index=('class1', 'class2', 'class3'))

df = pd.DataFrame( index=('class1', 'class2', 'class3')) 

for f in [df1, df2, df3]:
    first_col = f.iloc[:,0]
    df[f] = first_col.values
```

The expected output is a matrix with same formatting as below:

```
         A   C   E
class1   2  18  62
class2  46  46  11
class3  57  73  92
```

But this code did not work.

The question mirror this query, but the answers tried (below) did not work.
[How to add a new column to an existing DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/how-to-add-a-new-column-to-an-existing-dataframe)

> ```
> df.set_index([first_col], append=True)
>
> df.assign(f=first_col.values)
> ```

Comment: What is the expected output? Did you try to use `pd.concat`? `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)`

Comment: There are actually a variable number of data frames to process, not just three. I was trying to set up a loop for this reason.

Comment: please try to add your expected output to figure out what you want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is possible if change name of new columns in ouput DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=('class1', 'class2', 'class3')) 

r = [df1, df2, df3] 
for f in r: 
    first_col = f.iloc[:,0] 
    df[f.columns[0]] = first_col
print (df)
         A   C   E
class1  10  25  85
class2  45  57  48
class3  59  99  87
```

Better is use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with list comprehension for select first column:

```
r=[df1, df2, df3] 

df = pd.concat([f.iloc[:, 0] for f in r], axis=1)
print (df)
         A   C   E
class1   2  18  62
class2  46  46  11
class3  57  73  92
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a for loop or comprehension to perform merge operations

To merge the first column of each DataFrame, you can use the `concat()` function and `iloc()` method together from pandas as shown below code:

```
# Merge the first columns
merged_df = pd.concat([df1.iloc[:, 0], df2.iloc[:, 0], df3.iloc[:, 0]], axis=1)
merged_df
```

Output:

```
        A   C   E
class1  36  75  29
class2  68  48  74
class3  90  42  70
```