# Parallelize data ingestion for reading csv file using Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pyspark

I've prepared a code to read a huge CSV file (50gb) (500krecords with 30k columns) in chunks of 1000 records. There is a transformation involved to transpose the data into key value pairs. This is currently working in a sequential order. Is there a way to run those chunks in parallel? Will PySpark help here? The final file will be moved to Redshift.

```
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='bucket', Key = 'path')
csv_header =  pd.read_csv(obj['Body'], nrows=1).columns

obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='bucket', Key = 'path')
csv_iterator = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'], iterator=True, chunksize=1000,low_memory=False) 

i=0
c=0

print("Iteration Start!",time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime()))
for csv_chunk in csv_iterator:
    column_size = csv_header.size-csv_chunk.columns.size   
    csv_chunk[np.arange(column_size)]=None 
    chunk = pd.DataFrame(csv_chunk.values,columns=csv_header)
    if i==0:
        chunk.to_csv('temp_source.csv',mode = 'a')
    else:
        chunk.to_csv('temp_source.csv',mode = 'a',header=False)
    out = pd.melt(chunk,
              id_vars=['eid'],
              value_vars=chunk.columns[1:])
    if i==0:
        out.to_csv('temp_key_value.csv',mode='a')
    else:
        out.to_csv('temp_key_value.csv',mode='a',header=False)
    i=i+1
    c=c + csv_chunk.shape[0]
    print("Iteration ",i," Chunk - ",c," - ",time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime()))
    
print("Load Complete!",time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime()))
```

Trying to run read csv and transformations in parallel.

This is a follow-up from [Add N number of Empty Columns to a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77017050/12846804).

Comment: can you share a 1000-lines csv actual input file for testing (a link)?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't share the file. The dimension of the file is 500k x 30k

Comment: This is a follow-up from https://stackoverflow.com/q/77017050/12846804

Comment: "Trying to run read csv and transformations in parallel" Why? Might transformation not be done more efficiently in a  post-processing stage, using vectorization?

Comment: @WillGraham, can you just `pd.read_csv(obj['Body'], nrows=1000).to_csv('test.csv')` for that?

Comment: `if i==0:` (...) `if i==0:` Do you have the exact same block twice?

Comment: I would probably use `split` to split the original CSV file to 1000-line chunks, then run the program over them with e.g. `parallel`...

Comment: (However, all in all this sounds like a "you don't need Pandas"  problem – look at the `csv` module since you're essentially working with streaming...)

Comment: Not exactly focused on your question but a downstream issue.  Reading a single 50gb file into Redshift will be suboptimal (slow).  Redshift can read CSV files from S3 in parallel and greatly improve load time.  At least 1 file per slice in the cluster and at least 250mb per file.  50 1gb files would be great.

Comment: @Oca - I have used i to make sure I only add the header for the first iteration. The rest of the data is appended to it after that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721120/how-to-split-csv-files-as-per-number-of-rows-specified   If you need header info per split, just use this utility to make N files and then process those files parallely.